# PowerShell, formatting values in another culture

Tags: powershell, locale, number-formatting

Is there an easy way in PowerShell to format numbers and the like in another locale? I'm currently writing a few functions to ease SVG generation for me and SVG uses `.` as a decimal separator, while PowerShell honors my locale settings (`de-DE`) when converting floating-point numbers to strings.

Is there an easy way to set another locale for a function or so without sticking

```
.ToString((New-Object Globalization.CultureInfo ""))
```

after every `double` variable?

Note: This is about the *locale* used for formatting, *not* the format string.

(Side question: Should I use the invariant culture in that case or rather `en-US`?)

**ETA:** Well, what I'm trying here is something like the following:

```
function New-SvgWave([int]$HalfWaves, [double]$Amplitude, [switch]$Upwards) {
    "<path d='M0,0q0.5,{0} 1,0{1}v1q-0.5,{2} -1,0{3}z'/>" -f (
        $(if ($Upwards) {-$Amplitude} else {$Amplitude}),
        ("t1,0" * ($HalfWaves - 1)),
        $(if ($Upwards -xor ($HalfWaves % 2 -eq 0)) {-$Amplitude} else {$Amplitude}),
        ("t-1,0" * ($HalfWaves - 1))
    )
}
```

Just a little automation for stuff I tend to write all the time and the double values need to use the decimal point instead of a comma (which they use in my locale).

**ETA2:** Interesting trivia to add:

```
PS Home:> $d=1.23
PS Home:> $d
1,23
PS Home:> "$d"
1.23
```

By putting the variable into a string the set locale doesn't seem to apply, somehow.

Comment: It's interesting that `[Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture` doesn't work..

Comment: I've had problems only with 1.5 vs. 1,5, that's why inv. culture would work for me. It sounded to me like a batch task, so I thought you could run it in a separate powershell.exe session.

Comment: @stej: `[Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` determines the display language of _UI elements_, not number formatting; by contrast, it is `[Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` that determines number formatting; try (on a single line) `[Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 'de-DE'; 1.2`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a PowerShell function I use for testing script in other cultures. I believe it could be used for what you are after:

```
function Using-Culture ([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]$culture =(throw "USAGE: Using-Culture -Culture culture -Script {scriptblock}"),
                        [ScriptBlock]$script=(throw "USAGE: Using-Culture -Culture culture -Script {scriptblock}"))
{    
    $OldCulture = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
    $OldUICulture = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture
    try {
        [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $culture
        [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = $culture        
        Invoke-Command $script    
    }    
    finally {        
        [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $OldCulture        
        [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = $OldUICulture    
    }    
}

PS> $res = Using-Culture fr-FR { 1.1 }
PS> $res
1.1
```

Comment: Keith, could you explain me why this always returns my locale and not french? `[Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]'fr-FR';
[Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name`

Comment: Oops, it works. But if I run it one command after another, it doesn't. (= if I type it in console, each command on separate row)

Comment: Stej, good question. Type this at the command line and execute it over and over: `[Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`. Now execute this: `& { 1..5 | %{[Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId} }`. It would appear that as you execute commands interactively there's no guarantee they will execute on the same thread from one invocation to the next.  But inside a scriptblock, the same thread is used.

Comment: If you switch to STA (put the -STA argument on the PowerShell command-line), the thread will be reused (but the culture change still doesn't seem to stick past a single pipeline).

Comment: @Jaykul Confirmed. Starting PowerShell in single-threaded apartment with `-STA`, and typing (in **one** line): `[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]"ar-SA"; [DateTime]::Now; [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;` changes the culture to Arabic (Saudi Arabia), writes the current date and time in some Arabic way, and finally writes a thread ID. But after that the line `[DateTime]::Now; [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;` will use the original culture. The thread ID is the same, though.

Comment: In PS3 they actually changed things so they reset the culture. As far as I know, you have to use something like Keith Hill's script so that it all runs in one pipeline...

Comment: Great utility function. In PSv3+ with .NET v4.6+, use `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture = <culture-name>` to change the current culture (e.g., `fr-FR` for France). Unfortunately, up to _Windows PowerShell_ v5.1, this only takes effect for a _single command line_; e.g., `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture = 'fr-FR'; Get-Date; 1.2` works, but whatever you submit at the _next_ prompt will revert to the culture that was current at session startup time.
Fortunately, in PowerShell _Core_ as of at least v6.0.2, this problem has been fixed and the new culture stays in effect for the remainder of the session.

Answer (score 23):

While [Keith Hill's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2380257/45375) shows you how to change a script's current culture on demand (more modern alternative as of PSv3+ and .NET framework v4.6+:
`[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture = [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture`), there is ***no* need to change the culture**, because - as you've discovered in your second update to the question - **PowerShell's string *interpolation* - as opposed to using the `-f` operator - always uses the *invariant* rather than the *current* culture**:

In other words:

If you replace `'val: {0}' -f 1.2` with `"val: $(1.2)"`, the number literal `1.2` is *not* formatted according to the rules of the current culture.
You can verify in the console by running (*on a single line*; PSv3+, .NET framework v4.6+):

```bash
 PS> [cultureinfo]::currentculture = 'de-DE'; 'val: {0}' -f 1.2; "val: $(1.2)"
 val: 1,2 # -f operator: GERMAN culture applies, where ',' is the decimal mark
 val: 1.2 # string interpolation: INVARIANT culture applies, where '.' is the decimal mark.
```

Note: In *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, the change to a different culture remains in effect for the remainder of the session (as it arguably should for *Windows PowerShell* too, but doesn't).

---

**Background:**

By design,<sup>[1]</sup> but perhaps surprisingly, **PowerShell applies the *invariant* rather than the *current* culture in the following *string-related* contexts**, *if* the type at hand supports culture-specific conversion to and from strings:

As explained in [this in-depth answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30542422/45375), **PowerShell explicitly requests *culture-invariant* processing, *if possible***  - by passing the [`[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture) instance - in the following scenarios (the stringification PowerShell performs is the equivalent of calling `.psobject.ToString([NullString]::Value, [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)` on a value):

- When **string-interpolating**: if the object's type implements the `IFormattable` interface.
- When **casting**:

  - ***to* a string**, including ***implicit* conversion** when **binding to a `[string]`-typed parameter**: if the source type implements the [`[IFormattable]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iformattable) interface.
  - ***from* a string**: if the target type's static `.Parse()` method has an overload with an [`[IFormatProvider]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IFormatProvider)-typed parameter (which is an interface implemented by [`[cultureinfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo)).
- When **string-comparing** (`-eq`, `-lt`, `-gt`) , using a [`String.Compare()` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare) that accepts a `CultureInfo` parameter.
- Others?

Note that, separately, ***custom* stringification is applied in casts / implicit stringification for the following .NET types**:

- *Arrays* and, more generally, similar list-like collection types that PowerShell enumerates in the pipeline (see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65530467/45375) for what those types are).

  - The (stringified) *elements* of such types are concatenated with *spaces* (strictly speaking: with the string specified in the rarely used [`$OFS` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#ofs)); the stringification of the elements is recursively subject to the rules described here.
  - E.g, `[string] (1, 2)` yields `'1 2'`
- `[pscustomobject]`

  - Such instances result in a hashtable-*like* string format described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53107600/45375); e.g.:

    ```bash
    # -> '@{foo=1; bar=2.2}'; values are formatted with the *invariant* culture
    [string] ([pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1; bar = 2.2 })
    ```
  - The fact that calling `.ToString()` directly on a `[pscustomobject]` instance does *not* yield this representation and instead returns the empty string should be considered a *bug* - see [GitHub issue #6163](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6163).
- Others?

As for **the purpose of the [invariant culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture)**:

> The invariant culture is culture-insensitive; it is **associated with the English language but not with any country/region**.
> [...]
> Unlike culture-sensitive data, which is subject to change by user customization or by updates to the .NET Framework or the operating system, invariant culture data is **stable over time and across installed cultures** and cannot be customized by users. This makes the invariant culture particularly useful for operations that require culture-independent results, such as formatting and parsing operations that persist formatted data, or sorting and ordering operations that require that data be displayed in a fixed order regardless of culture.

**Presumably, it is the stability across cultures that motivated PowerShell's designers to consistently use the invariant culture when *implicitly* converting to and from strings**.

For instance, if you hard-code a date string such as `'7/21/2017'` into a script and later try to convert it to date with a `[date]` cast, PowerShell's culture-invariant behavior ensures that the script doesn't break even when run while a culture other than US-English is in effect - **fortunately, the invariant culture also recognizes ISO 8601-format date and time strings**;
e.g., `[datetime] '2017-07-21'` works too.

On the flip side, **if you do want to convert to and from *current*-culture-appropriate strings, you must do so *explicitly***.

To summarize:

- **Converting *to* strings**:

  - Embedding instances of data types with culture-sensitive-by-default string representations inside `"..."` yields a culture-*invariant* representation (`[double]` or `[datetime]` are examples of such types).
  - **To get a *current*-culture representation, call `.ToString()` explicitly or use [`-f`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f))**, the formatting operator (possibly inside `"..."` via an enclosing `$(...)`).
- **Converting *from* strings**:

  - A direct cast (`[<type>] ...`) only ever recognizes culture-*invariant* string representations.
  - **To convert from a *current*-culture-appropriate string representation (or a *specific* culture's representation), use the target type's static `::Parse()` method explicitly** (optionally with an explicit `[cultureinfo]` instance to represent a specific culture).

---

#### Culture-INVARIANT examples:

- **string interpolation** and **casts**:

  - `"$(1/10)"` and `[string] 1/10`

    - both yield string literal `0.1`, with decimal mark `.`, irrespective of the current culture.
  - Similarly, **casts *from* strings** are culture-invariant; e.g., `[double] '1.2'`

    - `.` is *always* recognized as the decimal mark, irrespective of the current culture.
    - Another way of putting it: `[double] 1.2` is *not* translated to the culture-*sensitive*-by-default method overload `[double]::Parse('1.2')`, but to the culture-*invariant* `[double]::Parse('1.2', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)`
- **string comparison** (assume that `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture='tr-TR'` is in effect - Turkish, where [`i` is NOT a lowercase representation of `I`](http://mattryall.net/blog/2009/02/the-infamous-turkish-locale-bug))

  - `[string]::Equals('i', 'I', 'CurrentCultureIgnoreCase')`

    - `$false` with the Turkish culture in effect.
    - `'i'.ToUpper()` shows that in the Turkish culture the uppercase is `İ`, not `I`.
  - `'i' -eq 'I'`

    - is still `$true`, because the *invariant* culture is applied.
    - implicitly the same as: `[string]::Equals('i', 'I', 'InvariantCultureIgnoreCase')`

---

#### Culture-SENSITIVE examples:

The current culture IS respected in the following cases:

- **With `-f`, the string-formatting operator** (as noted above):

  - `[cultureinfo]::currentculture = 'de-DE'; '{0}' -f 1.2` yields `1,2`
  - Pitfall: Due to [operator precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Operator_Precedence), any *expression* as the RHS of `-f` must be enclosed in `(...)` in order to be recognized as such:

    - E.g., `'{0}' -f 1/10` is evaluated as if `('{0}' -f 1) / 10` had been specified;
      use `'{0}' -f (1/10)` instead.
- ***Default* output to the console**:

  - e.g., `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture = 'de-DE'; 1.2` yields `1,2`
  - The same applies to output from cmdlets; e.g.,
    `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture = 'de-DE'; Get-Date '2017-01-01'` yields
    `Sonntag, 1. Januar 2017 00:00:00`
  - *Caveat*: In certain scenarios, literals passed to a script block as unconstrained parameters can result in culture-invariant default output - see [GitHub issue #4557](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4557) and [GitHub issue #4558](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4558).
- In (all?) **cmdlets**:

  - Those that that perform **equality comparisons**:

    - [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) with the `-Unique` switch; also note that - unusually - case-*sensitive* comparison is performed, and as of PowerShell 7.2.4 case-insensitivity isn't even available as an opt-in - see [GitHub issue #12059](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12059).
    - [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)
    - [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object)
    - Others?
  - Those that **write to files**:

    - [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) and [`Add-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content)
    - [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) and therefore its virtual alias, `>` (and `>>`)

      - e.g., `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture = 'de-DE'; 1.2 > tmp.txt; Get-Content tmp.txt` yields `1,2`
- Due to .NET's logic, **when using the static `::Parse()` / `::TryParse()` methods on number types such as [`[double]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.parse?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Double_Parse_System_String_)** while passing only the string to parse; e.g., with culture `fr-FR` in effect (where `,` is the decimal mark), `[double]::Parse('1,2')` returns double `1.2` (i.e., `1 + 2/10`).

  - *Caveat*: As [bviktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1708230/bviktor) points out, thousands separators are recognized by default, but in a very loose fashion: effectively, the thousands separator can be placed *anywhere* inside the integer portion, irrespective of how many digits are in the resulting groups, and a leading `0` is also accepted; e.g., in the `en-US` culture (where `,` is the thousands separator), `[double]::Parse('0,18')` perhaps surprisingly *succeeds* and yields `18`.

    - To suppress recognition of thousands separators, use something like `[double]::Parse('0,18', 'Float')`, via the [`NumberStyles` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?view=netframework-4.7.1)
- ***Unintentional* culture-sensitivity that *won't be corrected* to preserve backward compatibility**:

  - **In parameter-binding type conversions for compiled *cmdlets*** (but *PowerShell code* - scripts or functions - *is* culture-invariant) - see [GitHub issue #6989](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6989).
  - **In the `-as` operator** - see [GitHub issue #8129](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8129).
  - **In `[hashtable]` key lookups** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53324566/45375) and [GitHub issue #8280](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8280).
  - **[*Fixed in v7.1+*]** **In the LHS of `-replace` operations** - see [GitHub issue #10948](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10948).
- Others?

---

<sup>[1] The aim is to support *programmatic processing* using representations that do not vary by culture and do not change over time. See the linked quote from the docs later in the answer.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

I was thinking about how to make it easy and came up with accelerators:

```
Add-type -typedef @"
 using System;  

 public class InvFloat  
 {  
     double _f = 0;  
     private InvFloat (double f) {  
         _f = f;
     }  
     private InvFloat(string f) {  
         _f = Double.Parse(f, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
     }  
     public static implicit operator InvFloat (double f) {  
         return new InvFloat(f);  
     }  
     public static implicit operator double(InvFloat f) {  
         return f._f;
     }  
     public static explicit operator InvFloat (string f) {  
         return new InvFloat (f);
     }  
     public override string ToString() { 
         return _f.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
     }
 }  
"@
$acce = [type]::gettype("System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators") 
$acce::Add('f', [InvFloat])
$y = 1.5.ToString()
$z = ([f]1.5).ToString()
```

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the culture loaded in your environment,

```
    #>Get-Culture
    LCID             Name             DisplayName                                                                                                                                             
----             ----             -----------                                                                                                                                             
1031             de-DE            German (Germany)                                                                                                                                        

#>Get-UICulture

LCID             Name             DisplayName                                                                                                                                             
----             ----             -----------                                                                                                                                             
1033             en-US            English (United States)
```

it is possible to resolve this problem:

```
PS Home:> $d=1.23
PS Home:> $d
1,23
```

like this:

```
$d.ToString([cultureinfo]::CurrentUICulture)
1.23
```

Of course you need to keep in mind that if other users run the script with a different locale setting, the results may not turn out as originally intended.

Nevertheless, this solution could come in useful. Have fun!

Comment: ++ for a handy technique for _ad-hoc_ stringification in a _specific_ culture; to give the explicit equivalent of your example: `$d.ToString([cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('en-US'))`.
To stringify in the _invariant_ culture (which is ultimately what the OP wanted), it is simplest to _cast_ (`[string] $d`), or to use PowerShell's _string interpolation_ (`"$d"`).