# How to set culture in PowerShell?

Tags: .net, powershell, internationalization

Is there any PowerShell equivalent for:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

? Or how to set the force all stringfications to obey a culture independently from the machine configurations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
$currentThread = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread
$culture = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
$currentThread.CurrentCulture = $culture
$currentThread.CurrentUICulture = $culture
```

This idea came from:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160113133847/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/powershell/archive/2006/04/25/583235.aspx)

Comment: It does not throw for me, but the culture is not changed in this way.

Comment: @Roman I found out the problem with the statement and I corrected it. In C# it would work.

Comment: @XMLforDummies: your exception looks bad, as if something is very wrong in your PowerShell. Can you type this: `[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]`? Does it work or fail, too?

Comment: I see, the edited version works. Thanks, it is interesting to know.

Comment: No, it does not... This `[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` stil gets English (UK), not invariant.

Comment: Aha, it works until a command is running. Next command invoked from the prompt should take care of this again (if it needs to).

Comment: @Roman You mean that it only works for the current script file?

Comment: Yes. At least for me. Culture is not changed globally in this way.

Comment: @Roman I already expected that. It behaves the same way in C#. It sets the culture for the current thread alone.

Comment: I think PowerShell spawns pipelines in new threads... thus each command you run would need this set again.

Comment: Yep, run this a couple of times at the console `[threading.thread]::CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`.

Answer (score 7):

This is the function I use for testing string/formats in other cultures:

```
function Using-Culture (
  [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]
  $culture = (throw "USAGE: Using-Culture -Culture culture -Script {...}"),
  [ScriptBlock]
  $script = (throw "USAGE: Using-Culture -Culture culture -Script {...}"))
{
    $OldCulture = [Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
    $OldUICulture = [Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture    
    try {        
        [Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $culture        
        [Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = $culture        
        Invoke-Command $script    
    }    
    finally {        
        [Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $OldCulture        
        [Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = $OldUICulture    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For WinServer2012 and Win8 you can use [`Set-Culture`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852137.aspx). As `Set-Culture` sets the culture for your user, you'd have to open another powershell instance to benefit from that. Also it does not change the culture of running ps instances. Of course you could start up a new powershell instance in your current instance then. *This is not exactly what is asked for, but closely related.*

Would be neat, if they'd port that back to Win7 and Server 2008 or make it a feature of powershell itselft.

Comment: The linked document says "Sets the user culture for the current user account." - so it seems it doesn't just set this for the current process but globally.

Comment: @SebastianKrysmanski The behaviour is in fact a bit odd. It changes the culture of the user as promised but your powershell instance keeps  its culture: Open up a powershell, `Get-Culture` (gives en-US), then `Set-Culture de-DE`, using `Get-Culture` gives en-US again and a `date` formats as usual. But when you open up another powershell and `Get-Culture` it gives de-DE, `date` formats like Germans would do.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>This answer deals with the *current culture*, which determines settings such as date format, currency, number formatting, collating sequence, ...; by contrast, the *current UI culture*, determines the UI language (menus, error messages, ...); All elements discussed below have UI-culture analogs (e.g., `Get-UICulture` vs. `Get-Culture`, `$PSUICulture` vs. `$PSCulture` EXCEPT `Set-Culture`, for which there is no analog.</sup>

**Changing to a different culture**:

In the **.NET Framework v4.6** and higher, **you can now *assign* to `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture`** (previously, it was read-only<sup>[1]</sup>; the `[cultureinfo]` PS type accelerator was introduced in PSv3); e.g.:

```
[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture = 'de-DE'
```

is equivalent to (which also works in v4.5 or lower, down to at least v2):

```
[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 'de-DE'
```

**CAVEAT**: PowerShell uses the *invariant* culture in *string-related* contexts, *irrespective of what the current culture is* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375) of mine.

- Both methods **change the culture for the *current* PowerShell instance (thread) *only***.

  - **Caveat** [fixed in PowerShell *Core* as of at least v6.0.2]: As has been noted, in order to try this in an *interactive* PowerShell session, enter all commands on a *single* line, because the culture-changing effect is limited to a single command line (this still applies on PSv3+, even though consoles there run in STA mode by default); e.g., to print a German date:
    `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture = 'de-DE'; Get-Date # must be on same line`
- **For a *persistent* culture change for the current user**, use the **[`Set-Culture` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852137.aspx)**, but, as noted in [mbx's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24205300/45375), this change only takes effect for *future* PowerShell instances, NOT the current one.

---

**Querying culture settings:**

- **`[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture`** and `[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` reflect the *current* PowerShell instance's ***effective* culture**.
- By contrast, the **[`Get-Culture` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849930.aspx)** (PSv3+) and the automatic **`$PSCulture`** variable (PSv3+; read-only) invariably reflect the current PowerShell instance's culture at *startup* time; i.e., they **always reflect the current user's persistently configured culture at the time the current PowerShell instance was started** (irrespective of instance-only changes via `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture = ...` or *future* persistent changes via `Set-Culture` performed in that instance).

---

<sup>[1] See the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx); to determine whether you have at least v4.6 installed, look for the `Version:` value in the output from `Get-Item 'registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full'`.

Note that the *framework* version is distinct from the *CLR* (runtime) version as reported by `$PSVersionTable.CLRVersion`; for instance, the v4.6 *framework* is based on the v4.0 *CLR* - see the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049(v=vs.110).aspx).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.objectcmdletbase.culture%28VS.85%29.aspx) for details of `ObjectCmdletBase.Culture` Property.

> Gets and sets the value of the Culture
>   parameter of the derived cmdlet.

Comment: As I know nothing of PowerShell, could you provide a simple snippet that I could past on the first line of each script I have here so it will stringfy accordingly to the InvariantCulture?

Comment: Actually there is a better method here, with examples: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/04/25/583235.aspx

Answer (score 1):

`Set-Culture` works on local server but it does not work when you run it on remote computer

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock{
            #Requires -RunAsAdministrator
            Set-Culture -CultureInfo en-GB; 
            Set-TimeZone -Id "GMT Standard Time" 
        }
```

Comment: This is what happens in remote server: {Get-UICulture  - ui culture does not change}, {Get-Culture - current culture changes}. However it works fine when you run set-culture on local computer without the scriptblock. set-culture changes the ui culture too.