# DateTime parameter parsing has different locale

Tags: parsing, powershell, datetime, locale

I'm a little puzzled by how PowerShell treats a string that represents a DateTime when it comes down to parameters. My Script has a parameter definition as follows:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Kunde')]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='Kunde')]
    [string]$KdNr,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='Kunde')]
    [DateTime]$von,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='Kunde')]
    [DateTime]$bis,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='Kunde')]
    [string]$Empfaenger
)
```

I want to enter the following date: 1. April 2016 as my locale string `01.04.2016`. Now PowerShell does something that is unexpected (at least to me):

1. I enter the string `01.04.2016` at the command prompt when PowerShell queries the missing mandatory parameter. Then it gets parsed to 1. April 2016.
2. I enter the same string `01.04.2016` directly at the commandline like this `ZippenUndMailen.ps1 -von '01.04.2016'` and now PowerShell parses the string using the US notation as January 4th 2016.

I've got two questions:

1. Why does PowerShell parse the strings differently?
2. How do I best remedy that behaviour? The Script should be reused and called both manually and via TaskScheduler and this behaviour is rather counter intuitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce it too, despite my current culture being different from `en-us`. 
Try removing `[DateTime]` cast from your parameter definition (set it to `[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='Kunde')]$von`) and use `$von = [DateTime]::Parse($von, (Get-Culture))` in your code to force PS to use your current culture.

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359053/why-does-powershell-always-use-us-culture-when-casting-to-datetime):

> To prevent subtle internationalization issues from popping into your
>   scripts, PowerShell treats `[DateTime] '11/26/2007'` (a date constant)
>   like a language feature – just as it does `[Double] 10.5` (a numeric
>   constant.) Not all cultures use the decimal point as the fractions
>   separator, but programming languages standardize on it. Not all
>   cultures use the en-US DateTime format, resulting in millions of
>   internationalization bugs when people don’t consider the impact of
>   having their software run in those cultures.

Comment: That kinda solved it. Just had to remove the explicit `[string]` definition in the param definition. Otherwise PS would just convert the parsed `DateTime` back to a `string`. Without the explicit data type it works fine and is converted to a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

Adwaenyth, I can't replicate the differing time resolution you are seeing but it is most likely a culture issue... see this question regarding using culture in Powershell [How to set culture in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105224/how-to-set-culture-in-powershell)