# set-culture for Windows 7 system

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I need a universal way to change the Regional Format ( Control Panel->Region and Language->Formats->Format: ) that works for Windows 7, 8, and 10 via powershell.  This needs to be quick and used for automation, so GPO will not suffice.

As viewed in [How to set culture in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105224/how-to-set-culture-in-powershell)  It proposes the change of culture for the current thread.  There is a great cmdlet **set-culture** that works PERFECTLY for Windows 8 and 10, but is NOT supported on Windows 7.

```
[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture = "en-US"
```

Windows 7, this changes for the thread, but when I go to Control Panel, it does not change.

```
set-culture en-US
```

Changes for the next iteration of powershell and when you open Control Panel, the settings have changed.

Is there a way I can get this to work in powershell universally?  How do I get this to at least change on Windows 7, (I can switch on Win8 and 10 to use the cmdlet)  .NET framework 4.6.1 installed.