# powershell : changing the culture of current session

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-vista, powershell-2.0

I am using powershell on windows vista.
How do I change the culture of current session?
My computer's culture is tr-TR so I am getting the error messages on Turkish. I would like to change to EN?

any chance?

Comment: Does the solution to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379514/powershell-formatting-values-in-another-culture/ help any?

Comment: -look here [thecnet blog](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverpowershell/thread/f4190964-9974-410b-9915-c66966f10edc)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have a look here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/04/25/583235.aspx

and here:  http://poshcode.org/2226:

```
function Set-Culture([System.Globalization.CultureInfo] $culture)
{
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = $culture
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $culture
}
```

---

**Additional Info**

To find which values can be used for `$culture`:

- This will give you a list of Culture Types:

  ```
  [Enum]::GetValues([System.Globalization.CultureTypes])
  ```
- Selecting one of the above types (e.g. AllCultures) you can then list the available values of that type:

  ```
  [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultures( [System.Globalization.CultureTypes]::AllCultures )
  ```
- You can then use the Name or Number of the culture you're interested in with the `GetCultureInfo` method to retrieve the value you're after:

  ```
  $culture = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo(1033)
  $culture = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo('en-US')
  ```

NB: Thanks to implicit conversion, you could just pass the culture name or number (i.e. as a string or integer) to the `Set-Culture` method which would automatically be converted to the expected CultureInfo value.

Comment: Ehh... no. This doesn't work.
After you switch the culture, read the values out. 
$host or [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture will not be updated. 

Tested with PowerShell 5 on win 10 and server 2012.

Comment: +1 for "this doesn't work"... at least not to change the host culture. However, if you pop a `(Get-Date).ToString()` into the end of the function then you should see the function return a date in the culture specified.

Answer (score 4):

As the accepted solution by @manojlds actually doesn't work (PS 5.1 on Windows 10) here what works for me (found on [github](https://gist.github.com/sunnyone/7486486)):

```bsh
$culture = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")
$assembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.Management.Automation")
$type = $assembly.GetType("Microsoft.PowerShell.NativeCultureResolver")
$field = $type.GetField("m_uiCulture", [Reflection.BindingFlags]::NonPublic -bor [Reflection.BindingFlags]::Static)
$field.SetValue($null, $culture)
```

Comment: This seems to affect Get-UICulture, yet has no effect on the current session's error messages. Did it make a persistent change instead?