# How to change the culture of system in Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have tried using Set-Culture, but I found that this module is not available in powershell. I have have tried upgrading powershell, but this module is still not available.

Can anyone help me find another solution without using Set-Culture?

Comment: How to change the culture of system in windows server 2008 R2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [powershell : changing the culture of current session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052765/powershell-changing-the-culture-of-current-session)