# Change the current culture of a Powershell session, v3.0+ specific

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, culture, powershell-4.0

I want to change the culture of accepted data and errors in my current interactive Powershell session. I am aware of this question [powershell : changing the culture of current session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052765/powershell-changing-the-culture-of-current-session) and of this question [Changing current culture](https://superuser.com/questions/727459/changing-current-culture) on SuperUser. The main problem that it doesn't work with Powershell 3.0 and 4.0.

```
PS C:\users\me\Documents> [system.threading.thread]::currentthread.currentculture

LCID             Name             DisplayName
----             ----             -----------
1049             ru-RU            Русский (Россия)


PS C:\users\me\Documents> [system.threading.thread]::currentthread.currentculture=[system.globalization.cultureinfo]"en-US"
PS C:\users\me\Documents> [system.threading.thread]::currentthread.currentculture

LCID             Name             DisplayName
----             ----             -----------
1049             ru-RU            Русский (Россия)
```

UI culture also does not accept new settings. `Set-Culture` in total does not work, regardless of whether I'm using admin access or not - anyway, it shouldn't be affected by this, as the effect is only for a single process. The [`Using-Culture`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379514/powershell-formatting-values-in-another-culture/) from MSDN Powershell blog, adapted by SO community, works, but only partially, for example, with current culture of "ru-RU" I am able to get proper date from "6/19/15 2:26:02 PM" string, which is in the "en-US" culture via `Using-Culture "en-US" {get-date -date "6/19/15 2:26:02 PM"}`, but receiving an error in another language is not possible: say `Using-Culture "en-US" {$null.test='1'}` results in an error with Russian locale, as if the culture was not changed.

This behavior was tested on my local Win7 Professional workstation with Powershell 4.0 installed, and a Windows Server 2012 with Powershell 3.0 installed, which is required to parse wrongly localized date strings. The latter has UI culture of "en-US" and system locale "ru-RU".

So, is changing Powershell session's culture still possible with PS3 and above, and if yes, how? (Or is it bugs again, or change in PS3 that I am not aware of?)

Answer (score 3):

Changing culture only affects a the thread and is only applicable to that process.
Your PS window is launched under the current locale and therefore the thread has that locale. Typing "[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture" into a PS window launched under the current system locale, will always show that locale.

If you run this in ISE it should explain it little:

```
 function Set-Culture([System.Globalization.CultureInfo] $culture) {
[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = $culture
[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $culture }

Set-Culture en-US
[system.threading.thread]::currentthread.currentculture
Pause
```

Or, in a PS window:

```
function Set-Culture([System.Globalization.CultureInfo] $culture) { [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = $culture ; [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $culture } ; Set-Culture en-US ; [system.threading.thread]::currentthread.currentculture
```

It works fine.

If you want a PS window with a new culture, you'll need launch it using that culture, not try and change it afterwards.

Comment: To start a PSwindow under the culture, just add the following to either of the above: **start-process 'c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'**

Comment: I've tried this with no luck(keeps showing non english output), what i'm doing wrong?
`Set-Culture en-US
start-process 'c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'`
and inside i run `netsh wlan show drivers`

Comment: You can't do that. May I should clarify further, set culture must be done in the current process - either run the command in your new process window as part of the script or you can do something like Start-Job -scriptblock {function Set-Culture([System.Globalization.CultureInfo] $culture) { [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = $culture ; [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $culture } ; Set-Culture en-US ; etc.....}