# Change error message language in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to display errors in English in powershell so I can search for them more easily online.

At the moment when there's an error it's displayed in french and will look like this :

```
PS C:\Users\Olivier\lpthw> type nul > ex2.py
type : Impossible de trouver le chemin d'accès « C:\Users\Olivier\lpthw\nul », car il n'existe pas.
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ type nul > ex2.py
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\Olivier\lpthw\nul:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

Comment: Try if [changing Culture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36623000/503046) works.

Comment: Tried it, but errors are still in french

Comment: You could google on the stuff displayed in the `CategoryInfo` and/or `FullyQualifiedErrorId` which is in English..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**PowerShell (Core) 7+**:

Execute **`[cultureinfo]::CurrentUICulture = 'en-US'`** (see [`System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture)) in your session to make PowerShell emit English messages from then on.

To preset it for all your PowerShell sessions, add the line to your `$PROFILE` file<sup>[1]</sup>. (See below for how to change the display language for your Windows sessions *as a whole*, invariably persistently.)

**Caveat:** As of **v7.2.x**, ***only English* is supported, because PowerShell has not yet been localized** in the way that Windows PowerShell is - progress is being tracked in [GitHub issue #666](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/666).

However, once localization is complete you'll be able to use the above to switch your sessions to English (or any given language), even if a different UI language is in effect on your system (see below).

---

**Windows PowerShell**:

Due to what is arguably a bug (since fixed in PowerShell Core), **you cannot directly make changing the UI language "stick" for an an entire session**:

```
# !! Change of UI culture is effective only for a single command line
PS> [cultureinfo]::CurrentUICulture = 'en-US'; 1 / 0
Attempted to divide by zero.
...
```

(Even adding `[cultureinfo]::CurrentUICulture = 'en-US'` to your `$PROFILE` file doesn't help.)

Given that Windows PowerShell is no longer being actively developed, a fix is unlikely.

However, there are two **workarounds**:

- ***Either***: **Place this *unsupported, but effective* hack in your `$PROFILE` file**<sup>[1]</sup>, courtesy of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118816/45375) (streamlined):

  ```
  function Set-PowerShellUICulture { 
    param([Parameter(Mandatory)] [cultureinfo] $culture) 

    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load('System.Management.Automation').
      GetType('Microsoft.PowerShell.NativeCultureResolver').GetField('m_uiCulture', 'NonPublic, Static').
        SetValue($null, $culture)

  }

  # Example call: Set the UI culture to 'en-US' (US English)
  #               Use a value that `[cultureinfo]::new()` understands.
  Set-PowerShellUICulture en-US
  ```

  - **Caveats**:

    - This is *unsupported*, because it uses reflection to call a *non-public* type. That said, given that Windows PowerShell is no longer under active development, it is safe to assume that the hack will continue to work.
    - With the hack in effect, the [automatic `$PSUICulture` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psuiculture) does *not* reflect the effective UI culture, because its value is determined statically at session startup. However, [`Get-UICulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-uiculture) *does*.
    - The hack does *not* work in PowerShell (Core) 7+, but there you can simply place `[cultureinfo]::CurrentUICulture = 'en-US'`, as shown at the top, in your `$PROFILE`.
- ***Or***: **Change the display language for Windows *as a whole***, via the Settings application or the [`Set-WinUILanguageOverride`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-winuilanguageoverride) cmdlet (Windows 8+ / Server Windows 2012+); such a change is *persistent* and **requires a logoff or reboot**.

  - **Caveats**:

    - This means that all GUI elements, such as menus, will then be in the chosen language, across *all* applications (that support localization and the chosen language).
    - Also, the default *keyboard layout* will switch to the chosen language's.
    - Given that a logoff or reboot is required, this method is also inconvenient for experimenting with different languages.

---

**Prerequisite**: Irrespective of current limitations/bugs, **in order for switching to a different UI culture (display language) to even be possible fundamentally, it must already be *installed* as a display language**, via the Settings application (`Settings` > `Time & Language` > `Language`); with *US English* (`en-US`) that isn't a concern, because it comes preinstalled with Windows.

---

<sup>[1] The (current-user, current-host) profile file, whose full path is reflected in the automatic `$PROFILE` variable, may not yet exist on your system.

• To create it on demand, run `if (-not (Test-Path $PROFILE)) { New-Item -Force $PROFILE }`

• To edit it with Visual Studio Code, for instance, run `code $PROFILE` or, if no custom text editor is installed, use

`notepad $PROFILE`

Either way, if there's a chance that the file's content will (possibly over time) contain non-ASCII characters (e.g., `é`), be sure to save the file as *UTF-8 with BOM*, which works in both PowerShell (Core) 7+ and Windows PowerShell.

For more information, see the conceptual [about_Profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) help topic.</sup>