# What is the internationalization (translation) status of PowerShell 7.*?

Tags: powershell

I could not find an answer on their github. I think all messages and errors are in English on my system with PowerShell 7.1.4.

[image]
[image]

Although Get-UICulture, Get-Culture, $PSUICulture, $PSCulture are all fr-FR. I forced an update-help just in case to no avail.

Can you confirm that PowerShell 7 is not translated yet ? If so, is it in process ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the language/culture settings. `Stop-Process` needs a process object not a string. Try `Get-Process notepad | Stop-Process`

Comment: @Scepticalist Did you read my question ? I provoked this error on purpose to show that messages are in English instead of French. Your answer could not be more irrelevant.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58184208/change-error-message-langage-in-powershell . No, PS v7 isn't localised.

Answer (score 1):

There is an [issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/666) on powershell github about how localization advance.