# PowerShell outputting array items when interpolating within double quotes

Tags: powershell, string-interpolation

I found some strange behavior in PowerShell surrounding arrays and double quotes. If I create and print the first element in an array, such as:

```
$test = @('testing')
echo $test[0]

Output:
testing
```

Everything works fine. But if I put double quotes around it:

```
echo "$test[0]"

Output:
testing[0]
```

Only the $test variable was evaluated and the array marker [0] was treated literally as a string. The easy fix is to just avoid interpolating array variables in double quotes, or assign them to another variable first. But is this behavior by design?

Comment: It is not obvious, but ultimately this is a duplicate of [How can you use an object's property in a double-quoted string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1145704/45375).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

So when you are using interpolation, by default it interpolates just the next variable in toto. So when you do this:

```
"$test[0]"
```

It sees the $test as the next variable, it realizes that this is an array and that it has no good way to display an array, so it decides it can't interpolate and just displays the string as a string. The solution is to explicitly tell PowerShell where the bit to interpolate starts and where it stops:

```
"$($test[0])"
```

Note that this behavior is one of my main reasons for using formatted strings instead of relying on interpolation:

```
"{0}" -f $test[0]
```

Comment: Your solutions are effective, but your explanation isn't correct. String interpolation is _syntactically_ limited to parsing only `$<variableName>`. Any character that is not valid in a variable name stops parsing, such as `[` in this case. PowerShell happily expands the _entire_ array `$test`, namely by separating the elements with a single space between the elements (by default). The following `[0]` is simply treated as a literal and has no bearing on how `$test` is converted to a string.

Comment: What do you mean by *"in toto"*?

Answer (score 12):

[EBGreen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9196650/45375) contains effective *solutions*, but only a cursory *explanation* of **PowerShell's *string expansion* (string interpolation)**:

- **Only variables *by themselves* can be embedded *directly* inside double-quoted strings (`"..."`)** (by contrast, single-quoted strings (`'...'`), as in many other languages, are for *literal* contents).

  - This applies to both regular variables and variables referencing a specific namespace; e.g.:
    `"var contains: $var"`, `"Path: $env:PATH"`
  - If the first character *after* the variable name can be mistaken for part of the name - which notably includes `:` - **use `{...}` around the variable name to disambiguate**; e.g.:
    `"${var}"`, `"${env:PATH}"`
  - To **use a `$` as a *literal*, you must escape it with `` ` ``**, PowerShell's escape character; e.g.:
    `` "Variable `$var" ``
- Any character *after* the variable name - including `[` and `.` is treated as a *literal* part of the string, so **in order to *index into* embedded variables (`$var[0]`) or to *access a property* (`$var.Count`), you need `$(...)`**, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) (in fact, `$(...)` allows you to embed entire *statements*); e.g.:

  - `"1st element: $($var[0])"`
  - `"Element count: $($var.Count)"`
  - `"Today's date: $((Get-Date -DisplayHint Date | Out-String).Trim())"`
- **Stringification** (to-string conversion) is applied to any variable value / evaluation result that isn't already a string:

  - **Caveat**: Where culture-specific formatting can be applied, PowerShell chooses the ***invariant* culture**, which largely coincides with the **US-English date and number formatting**; that is, dates and numbers will be represented in US-like format (e.g., month-first date format and `.` as the decimal mark).
  - **In essence, the `.ToString()` method is called** on any resulting non-string object or collection (strictly speaking, it is `.psobject.ToString()`, which overrides `.ToString()` in some cases, notably for arrays / collections and PS custom objects)

    - Note that this is *not* the same representation you get when you output a variable or expression directly, and many types have *no* meaningful default string representations - they just return their full type *name*.
      However, you can **embed `$(... | Out-String)` in order to explicitly apply PowerShell's default output formatting**.
    - For a more comprehensive discussion of stringification, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375).

---

As stated, using **`-f`, the string-formatting operator (`<format-string> -f <arg>[, ...]`)** is an **alternative** to string interpolation that separates the literal parts of a string from the variable parts:

```
'1st element: {0}; count: {1:x}'  -f  $var[0], $var.Count
```

- Note the **use of `'...'` on the LHS**, because the format string (the template) is itself a *literal*. Using `'...'` in this case is a good habit to form, both to signal the intent of using literal contents and for the ability to embed `$` characters without escaping.
- In addition to **simple positional placeholders (`{0}` for the 1st argument. `{1}` for the 2nd, ...)**, you may optionally exercise more **formatting control over the to-string conversion**; in the example above, `x` requests a *hex* representation of the number.
  For available formats, see the documentation of the .NET framework's [`String.Format` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format), which the `-f` operator is based on.
- Pitfall: `-f` has high [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operator_precedence), so be sure to **enclose RHS expressions other than simple index or property access in `(...)`**; e.g., `'{0:N2}' -f 1/3` won't work as intended, only `'{0:N2}' -f (1/3)` will.
- **Caveats**: There are **important differences** between string interpolation and `-f`:

  - **Unlike expansion inside `"..."`, the `-f` operator *is* culture-sensitive:**

    - Therefore, the following two seemingly equivalent statements do *not*
      yield the same result:

      ```
           PS> [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture='fr'; $n=1.2; "expanded: $n"; '-f: {0}' -f $n

           expanded: 1.2
           -f: 1,2
      ```
    - Note how only the `-f`-formatted command respected the French (`fr`) decimal mark (`,`).
      Again, see the [previously linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375) for a comprehensive look at when PowerShell is and isn't culture-sensitive.
  - **Unlike expansion inside `"..."`, `-f` stringifies arrays as `<type-name>[]`:**

    ```
       PS> $arr = 1, 2, 3; "`$arr: $arr"; '$arr: {0}' -f (, $arr)

        $arr: 1 2 3
        $arr: System.Object[]
    ```

    - Note how `"..."` interpolation created a space-separated list of the stringification of all array elements, whereas `-f`-formatting only printed the array's type name.
      (As discussed, `$arr` inside `"..."` is equivalent to:
      `(1, 2, 3).psobject.ToString()` and it is the generally invisible helper type `[psobject]` that provides the friendly representation.)
    - Also note how `(, ...)` was used to wrap array `$arr` in a helper array that ensures that `-f` sees the expression as a *single operand*; by default, the array's elements would be treated as *individual* operands.

Answer (score 10):

In such cases you have to do:

```
echo "$($test[0])"
```

Another alternative is to use string formatting

```
echo "this is {0}" -f $test[0]
```

Note that this will be the case when you are accessing properties in strings as well. Like `"$a.Foo"` - should be written as `"$($a.Foo)"`