# Powershell: AD array export auto-generate "pointer"

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, export-to-csv, multivalue

I would like to export several multi-value "fields" from Microsoft Active Directory. Instead of defining all "array pointers" manually I want to generate them automatically.

I already checked
[Powershell outputting array items when interpolating within double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196525/powershell-outputting-array-items-when-interpolating-within-double-quotes) and tried out several alterantives but I always get stuck with the expressions

```
$SearchBases ='dummy.com','dummy2.com'
$csv_file_path = "C:\Test\Export.csv"
$properties_select = ''
$properties_multivalue = 'proxyAddresses','showInAddressBook','memberOf'

# go through each multi_value property and automatically generate 8 fields for upto 8 array elements
ForEach($prop in $properties_multivalue) {
    for ($i=0; $i -le 8; $i++) {
        $properties_select += @{Name=$prop+'_'+$i; Expression={$_.$($prop[$i])}}
    }
}
ForEach($SearchBase in $SearchBases) {
    Get-ADObject -filter 'objectClass -eq "contact"' -SearchBase $SearchBase -properties $properties_multivalue 
    |SELECT-Object $properties_select 
    |Export-Csv -Append -Force -Delimiter ";" -NoClobber -Encoding UTF8 -path $csv_file_path
}
```

I suspect that i do something wrong at

```
$properties_select += @{Name=$prop+'_'+$i; Expression={$_.$($prop[$i])}}
```

Any help/hints are useful.

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you need to fix:

The resulting value of `$properties_multivalue` will be a string and not an array of hashtables, so change line 3 to:

```
$properties_select = @()
```

The second thing is the `Expression` scriptblock - by the time `Select-Object` executes inside the second loop, `$prop` and `$i` will resolve to `memberOf` and `8` respectively, the last two values that were assigned to them in the first loop.

To have the individual scriptblocks "remember" the values as they were at the time of assignment, you'll need to close over them with the `GetNewClosure()` method:

```
$properties_select += @{Name=$prop+'_'+$i; Expression={$_.$($prop[$i])}.GetNewClosure()}
```

Additionally, I think you'll need to reorder the evaluation of the variables inside the `Expression` to: `$($_.$prop)[$i]` (ie. reference `$_.memberOf` first, then grab the value at index `$i` of that value)

Comment: First of all thank you for your quick response. 
Regarding $properties_multivalue = @() I suppose you mean $properties_select, because $properties_select is in line 3 and currently has an empty string

regarding GetNewClosure(): Thanks for the fix - i would never have thought it.

regarding expression, I changed the expression as suggested $($_.$prop)[$i]

but i still have one challenge with the expor in regards to ,'showInAddressBook','memberOf','postOfficeBox','postalAddress','otherTelephone'

it seems, these fields are multi-value but not indexed.

Comment: @Christian correct, updated the answer to mention `$properties_select`. Can you describe in more detail what your "challenge" is regarding these additional properties?

Comment: Currently i get the following output for e.g. memberOf:
memberOf1|memberof2|memberOf3|MemberOf4|....
C|N|=|T|....
It devides the DN into individual characters
Thus my bestguess multivalue but not indexed

if i use 
    $properties_select += @{Name="$prop"; Expression={$($_.$prop) -join ";"}.GetNewClosure()} instead, i get the error message "you must provide a value expression following the '-join' operator."

Comment: The other issue was caused by something else thus I mark this question as resolved Thanks @Matthias for the help!