# How can use $args inside a where-object and invoke command i n powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the next code, but when i use the arguments, it doesn't work like I try to find all the txt files in one drive:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $param3 -Credential $cred -ArgumentList $param4,$param5,$param6,$param7 -ScriptBlock {$A = Get-ChildItem $args[0] -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.name -match ".*$args[1].*"} |  Format-Table Name, CreationTime, Length, FullName -auto***'
```

*The variable `$param5` has the text ".txt"

Comment: Given that `-match` performs _substring_ matching by default, you needn't surround a  search term with `.*`, so you could just use `$args[1]` by itself, but the only real problem with your answer is the direct use of `$args[1]` inside `"..."` - as an _expression_, it must be enclosed in `$(...)` - `".*$($args[1]).*"` - as explained in the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50215337/45375).

Answer (score 1):

Take the quotes and periods off.  That would never work, even locally.

```
where-object { $_.name -match $args[1] } 
where name -match $args[1]
```

This doesn't seem to be well documented, but you can add a param section to the script block.

```
invoke-command c001 { param ($param1,$param2) echo $param1 $param2 } -args 1,2
```