# How to reference an index in a string array

Tags: powershell

I have this in my code

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
   [string[]]$NameArray = @(),
)
NameArray += "data"
Write-Host "Name is : $NameArray[0]"
```

The above appends `[0]` to the output. so I get

```
Name is data[0]
```

Any suggestion on how I can tell it that the [0] is the index and not text to be appended ?

Comment: `"Name is : ($NameArray[0])"` or `'Name is : {0}' -f $NameArray[0]`

Comment: The first one fails

Comment: "Name is : $($NameArray[0])" <- $ is missing

Comment: @Patrick that worked can you put that as the answer

Comment: Please see the linked post and, for detailed information, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50215337/45375).