# Passing $args[x] in an if statement in .ps1 (PowerShell) does not seem to work when it does not exist

Tags: powershell, if-statement

Suppose I have the following **testArgsX.ps1** file:

```
$ARG_X_PARAMETER=1
If ($args[0] -ne "") {
    echo ARGS[X]="`"$args[0]`""
    $ARG_X_PARAMETER=$args[0]
}
echo ARG_X_PARAMETER=$ARG_X_PARAMETER
```

When I execute it either in a command prompt (`C:\Test> powershell .\testArgsX.ps1`) or in PowerShell prompt (`PS C:\Test> .\testArgsX.ps1`), it outputs the following:

```
ARGS[X]="[0]"
ARG_X_PARAMETER=
```

It seems that `$args[0]`, in the if-condition, is not interpreted as a scalar value. Although I understand there are 2 ways to circumvent this problem (shown below). I want to know why it does not interpret it as a scalar value and if there is a way to fix it so that it does.

1. Take out the entire if statement (`If ( ... ) { ... }`) and replace it with `Param ( [Int]$RUN_JUST_ONCE = 1 )`
2. Change the if condition from `If ($args[0] -ne "") {` to `If ($args.Length -gt 0) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$args[0]` *is* a scalar, but **accessing a *non-existent array element* in PowerShell returns `$null`**<sup>[1]</sup>, and `$null` is indeed *not* equal to the empty string (`""` or `''`).

- Therefore, you should test for `$null`.

  - Note that testing for `$null` is best performed by placing `$null` on the *LHS* (`$null -ne $args[0]`), because on the RHS it would act as a *filter* instead of returning a *Boolean* in case the other operand happens to be an *array*.
- Also, note that i**n order to use an *expression* such as `$args[0]` inside `"..."`, an *expandable* (interpolating) string, you must use `$()`**, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--); without it, `$args` as a whole is expanded, and `[0]` is used *verbatim* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50215337/45375)
- `echo` is a built-in alias for the [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) cmdlet, whose explicit use is rarely needed; simply using a command or expression whose output is neither captured nor redirected is *implicitly* output.

To put it all together:

```
$ARG_X_PARAMETER=1
If ($null -ne $args[0]) {
    "ARGS[X]=`"$($args[0])`""
    $ARG_X_PARAMETER=$args[0]
}

"ARG_X_PARAMETER=$ARG_X_PARAMETER"
```

---

Alternatively, *declare parameters* for your script, which also makes it easy to assign default values:

```
param(
  # This implicitly becomes the 1st positional parameter.
  $ARG_X_PARAMETER = 1
)

"ARG_X_PARAMETER=$ARG_X_PARAMETER"
```

By default, parameters are *positional*, which means they can be used *unnamed* (e.g. `testArgsX.ps1 42`), though using the name explicitly is always an option (e.g.
`testArgsX.ps1 -ARG_X_PARAMETER 42`) - though a better name is the probably called for.

PowerShell optionally allows you to assign a *data type* to parameters and use a variety of attributes, notably ones for argument validation.

See [about_Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functionsfunctions-with-parameters) and [about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters).

---

<sup>[1] With [`Set-StrictMode -Version 3`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) or higher in effect, accessing a non-existent element causes a *statement-terminating error* instead.</sup>