# In Powershell Why might a foreach-object loop not let you retrieve individual values from an array?

Tags: arrays, powershell, foreach, foreach-object, parameter-splatting

Note the following output.
$Names is an array with two values.
$Machinename is an array with two values.

Their positional values within the array are retrieved accurately outside of a foreach loop.
When fetched within a foreach loop the value requested for the first position in the array i.e. $Names[0] ignores the positional call of [0]..... I need to be able to retrieve that value by itself..... Ultimately I will need to interate through each value to input to a command...

```
PS C:\Users\lab> $Names

john
jeff
PS C:\Users\lab> $Names[0]

john
PS C:\Users\lab> $Names[1]

jeff
PS C:\Users\lab> $Machinename

dev1
dev2
PS C:\Users\htlab> $Machinename | ForEach-Object  { Write-Output "$Names[0]"}

john jeff[0]
john jeff[0]
```

Sample Script:

```
$Names = 'john', 'jeff'
$machinename = 'dev1', 'dev2'
$Machinename | ForEach-Object  {Write-Output "$Names[0]"}
```

Comment: This is due to the `"` double-quotes - the string expansion routine in PowerShell doesn't recognize complex expressions. `$Machinename | ForEach-Object  {Write-Output $Names[0]}` will work just fine

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50215337/45375) to the linked duplicate provides a detailed explanation, but in short: inside `"..."`, if you want to reference an expression that goes beyond a simple variable reference (e.g., `$var`), you need to enclose it in `$(...)` (e.g., `$($var[0])`)

Comment: Thank you. This answered the immediate question and helps me understand how to reach my later objective. Gave me the fish, the pole, and the know how!

Answer (score 4):

You're not evaluating the array. By writing `"$Names[0]"` it is the equivalent of `$Names + "[0]"`.

You need to nest the evaluation inside `$(...)`.

Try this:

```
$Machinename | ForEach-Object  {Write-Output "$($Names[0])"}
```

That gives me:

```
john
john
```

---

Equally, as pointed out in the comments, this works too:

```
$Machinename | ForEach-Object  {Write-Output $Names[0]}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining what was actually happening. Knowing that actually gave me an idea for when i could use something like this when i actually want this behavior

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, as it seemed to work for me, unless thats not what you're asking,

```
for (($i = 0); $i -lt $names.Count; $i++)
{
 $Names[$i] + ":" + $Machinename[$i]
}
```

Output:

```
John:dev1
Jeff:dev2
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It might give the OP the desired result, but the specific question is "Why might a foreach-object loop not let you retrieve individual values from an array?"

Comment: @Enigmativity fair enough!

Comment: Thank you for the incrementor syntax, while it doesnt address my immediate question, as novice as i am to this, its sure to be helpful with one of my other automation tasks.