# How to add a line to .txt file with special characters and variables in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell file e.g. `C:\MyPowerShell.ps1` and I would like to have the following line there:

```
$myNewVariable = "Lukas"
```

Where string Lukas will be taken from variable `$name`. The variable `$name` will be declared before I run a command to do this action. I would like to use another PowerShell command to do that.

```
$name = "Lukas" <br>
Add-Content C:\MyPowerShell.txt ???
```

Please help me ;-)

Comment: Where is "there"? On the first line of the file? Last line? In the middle somewhere? What's already in the file?

Comment: ``'$myNewVariable = "Lukas"'` | Add-Content -Path 'C:\MyPowerShell.ps1'``. If you enclose the string in single quotes, PowerShell won't expand the variables inside, so the string is taken literally

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen There means only this single line.

Comment: @Theo But Lukas should be taken from another variable e.g. $name = "Lukas" and used in the command

Comment: You would like to add the value of $name to the file C:\MyPowerShell.txt?  

If so, just pipe it...  
$name | Out-File c:\MyPowerShell.txt -Append

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or use the `-f` [Format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#format-operator--f):

```
$name = 'Lukas'
Add-Content -Path 'C:\MyPowerShell.txt' -Value ('$myNewVariable = "{0}"' -f $name)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use an [*expandable (interpolating) string*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) (`"..."`)** in which you individually `` ` ``-escape `$` characters in tokens you do *not* want to be expanded as variable references / subexpressions; similarly, escape embedded `"` characters as `` `" `` (`""` would work too):

```sh
$name = 'Lucas'
Add-Content C:\MyPowerShell.txt -Value "`$myNewVariable = `"$name`""
```

**Alternatively, use the `-f` operator**, as shown in [Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68863541/45375).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50215337/45375) compares and contrasts these two approaches.