# What does $($variableName) mean in expandable strings in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, syntax, string-interpolation

I've seen a number of example scripts online that use this. Most recently, I saw it in a script on [automating TFS](http://programmaticponderings.wordpress.com/2012/04/15/automating-task-creation-in-team-foundation-server-with-powershell/):

```
[string] $fields = "Title=$($taskTitle);Description=$($taskTitle);Assigned To=$($assignee);"
$fields += "Area Path=$($areaPath);Iteration Path=$($iterationPath);Discipline=$($taskDisciplineArray[$i]);Priority=$($i+1);"
$fields += "Estimate=$($taskEstimateArray[$i]);Remaining Work=$($taskRemainingArray[$i]);Completed Work=$($tasktaskCompletedArray[$i])"
```

From what I can tell, `$($taskTitle)` seems to be equivalent to `$taskTitle`. Am I missing something? Is there any reason to use the parentheses and extra dollar sign?

Comment: FYI in *this* case `"Area Path=$($areaPath);"` the parens are unnecessary. `"Area Path=$areaPath;"` would work equally well.  That is, simple variable expansion just works within a double quoted string.  You need the parens when you need to evaluate an expression like $($variable.property) or $($variable + 1).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The syntax helps with evaluating the expression inside it.

```
$arr = @(1,2,3)

$msg1 = "$arr.length"
echo $msg1 # prints 1 2 3.length - .length was treated as part of the string

$msg2 = "$($arr.length)"
echo $msg2 # prints 3
```

You can read more at http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html

Answer (score 28):

To complement [Amith George's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13615748/45375) with more **background information**:

> From what I can tell, `$($taskTitle)` seems to be equivalent to `$taskTitle`.

Indeed, in the context of **`"..."`, an *expandable string*** (interpolating string):

- **You do NOT need `$(...)` with a *simple variable reference*** such as **`$taskTitle`** or **`$env:HOME`**

  - Sometimes you must (or may choose to) use the form `${taskTitle}` or `${env:HOME}` - i.e., `{...}` around the identifier - so as to disambiguate the variable name from subsequent characters in the string.
- **You DO need `$(...)` for *anything else***:

  - *accessing a property*; e.g.:
    `"count is: $($var.Count)"`
  - embedding an *expression*; e.g.:
    `"path prefix: $($var + '/')"`
  - embedding entire *commands* (possibly even *multiple* ones); e.g.:
    `"file names: $(Get-ChildItem *.txt | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)"`

In short:

- `$(...)` inside "`...`" is needed for anything other than simple variable references and allows you to embed entire *statements* inside `"..."`; as usual, when the string is evaluated, the `$(...)` part is replaced with the (stringified) *output* from the embedded statement(s).
- If you don't want to think about when `$(...)` is and isn't needed, you can choose to *always* use it (e.g., `$($taskTitle)`), but note that it's cumbersome to type and visually "noisy".

  - **Caveat**: There is an ***edge case* where the behavior of `$($var)` is *not* the same as that of `$var` / `${var}`**, namely if `$var` is a *collection* (implementing `[System.Collections.IEnumerable]`) that happens to contain only a *single item*  - see [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral)'s comments below.
- Unless the referenced variable's / embedded statement's value already is a string, it is **stringified** using the .NET **`.ToString()` method**, with the notable twist that types that support *culture-sensitive* stringification are stringified **with the *invariant culture***, which, loosely speaking, is like US-English format; e.g., `"$(1.2)"` *always* yields `1.2`, even in cultures where `,` is the decimal mark; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375) of mine for more.

**Documentation**:

The official name for **`$(...)` is the *subexpression operator***, as (tersely) documented in [`Get-Help about_Operators`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators), though the explanation there doesn't discuss the operator's specific use in the context of expandable strings.

Conversely, [`Get-Help about_Quoting_Rules`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules), which discusses string literals including expandable strings, shows *examples* of `$(...)` use only in the context of expandable strings.

Comment: BTW, `"${variable}"` and `"$($variable)"` not always return the same result.

Comment: Here is example: [gist](https://gist.github.com/PetSerAl/d6336e2bb76388af59e45f5942fb6935) or [tio.run](https://tio.run/##vY69CsIwFEb3@xSXkiEB6QMEHNog0tkxdIjlgkKaSJJSpPbZY/1DcBAnv@2Dc@Cc/EghHsjanDtrYsQKJe7OMVFfKm8tdenoXSybjRt6CmZvCSfAZfoLlXxocUvpfbl4arcFSkNwyFe6bqV0NHIhyg/8Ds8wAzy66r92qZ@7FE7LBWZwjbp6aQAFm8x8YZwZUeR8BQ)

Comment: As for explanation: it is direct consequences of difference between `${a}.GetType().FullName` and `$($a).GetType().FullName`; and how collection types stringified.

Comment: *this only seems to affect single-item collections, correct?* As far as I understand how it work, yes it is. To be equivalent of `"${variable}"` it need to be `"$(,$variable)"`.