# powershell for concatenating multiple strings

Tags: powershell, concatenation

In Powershell, how can I join 5 strings into one string.

```
 $s1='This`-string
 $s2='is' -string
 $s3='a'  -string
 $s4='good' -string
 $s5='thing' -string
 $s6=$s1+$s2+$s3+$s4+$s5
 write-host"result is "$s6-->Thisisagoodthing
```

Comment: Please mention your issue properly with details.Question seems broken.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [How to concatenate strings and variables in Powershell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113413/how-to-concatenate-strings-and-variables-in-powershell)

Comment: What's wrong with the current answers? None is selected, but both seem correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use :

```
> $s6="$s1$s2$s3$s4$s5"
>
> Write-Host "result is $s6"
```

Comment: For displaying purpose it is working but I want the entire result in a string variable..which is not working.Can you please check it once and revert to me.

Comment: @Chaitanya chaitanya your are wrong $s6 is a string var. This is the good answer or I don't understand your question ?

Answer (score 1):

You can literally "join" your strings with the [`-join`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847757.aspx) operator:

```
$s6 = $s1,$s2,$s3,$s4,$s5 -join ""
```

Or, without specifying a delimiter:

```
$s6 = -join @($s1,$s2,$s3,$s4,$s5)
```