# Powershell Echo Statement + Variable In One line

Tags: powershell, echo

I'm running a script, and I want it to print a "statement + variable +  statement" at the end [when successful]. I've tried a few thing but it always returns as 3 separate lines, instead of one. The Echo "" before and after is just to make it easier to read when printed by spacing it out, I've tried it with and without and I get the same result.

```
$filename = "foo.csv"

    echo ""
    echo "The file" $filename "has been processed."
    echo ""
```

I get this:

```
The file
foo.csv
has been processed.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate strings and variables in PowerShell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113413/how-to-concatenate-strings-and-variables-in-powershell)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you use double quotes you can reference the variable directly in the string as they allow variable expansion, while single quotes do not allow this.

```
$filename = "foo.csv"
Write-Output "The file $filename has been processed."

-> The file foo.csv has been processed.
```

Also, `echo` is actually just an alias for `Write-Output`, so I've used the full name.

Comment: So simple. I got thrown off because it gets grayed out. I thought it was being converted to plain text. Thanks.

Comment: I'd certainly recommend reading up on [double vs single quotes](http://jon.netdork.net/2015/09/08/powershell-and-single-vs-double-quotes/), such a small thing can have a very big effect :)

Comment: this not work properly with $args[0] if they are few - its print it all args :/

Comment: @GorodeckijDimitrij yes, arrays and strings need to be handled differently.

Answer (score 13):

```
echo ("The file "+ $filename +" has been processed.")
```

Comment: Please add a description to ur answer

Answer (score 7):

In powershell, you can use Write-Host as follows:

```
$filename = "foo.csv"
Write-Host 'The file' $filename 'has been processed.'

-> The file foo.csv has been processed.
```

Comment: When writing out an `object` then `Write-Host` will give you the object's type, not its contents. Better to use`Write-Output`