# How to pass two strings to a PowerShell function?

Tags: string, function, powershell, oop, concatenation

How do I pass `$dir` and `$file`, then [concatenate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15113413/4531180) them to a single path?

Output:

```
posh> 
posh> pwsh ./worker.ps1
dir is /home/nicholas/powershell/regex a.log
file is 
full is /home/nicholas/powershell/regex a.log/
posh>
```

library:

```
function SearchFile($dir,$file)
{
"dir is $dir"
"file is $file"

$full = [string]::Concat("full is ",$dir,"/",$file)
$full
#$pattern='(?=.*?foo)(?=.*?bar)'
#$string = Get-Content $full
#$result = $string | Select-String $pattern
#$result
}
```

worker:

```
. /home/nicholas/powershell/functions/library.ps1


$dir = "/home/nicholas/powershell/regex"
$file = "a.log"

SearchFile($dir,$file)
```

I seem to be passing an array of sorts for `$dir` and nothing is getting assigned for `$file` in `SearchFile` as expected.

Comment: when calling a function, DO NOT use `()` around your function parameters. [*grin*] just put them there something like `SearchFile $dir $file`.

Comment: that works @Lee_Dailey thanks

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped a bit ... [*grin*]

Comment: yes, believe it or not, I actually have a powershell book on my kindle.  it covers everything I don't need to know..lol.  I just randomly stumbled on how to even declare functions as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be done in a simpler way :

```
function SearchFile ($var_1, $var_2) {
    $full_path = "$var_1/$var_2"
    $full_path # Output --> C:/temp/test.txt
}

$my_dir  = "C:/temp"
$my_file = "test.txt"

SearchFile $my_dir $my_file # Do not use coma when calling a Function
```