# Place Variable value inside "" in Powershell

Tags: powershell, variables, powershell-4.0

I am writing a small script in powershell and want to build a variable in a particular format.

```
$name="abc"
$json = '{\"name\":\"$name\",\"projectId\":\"10034\"}'
$json
```

when I am printing the value the value appears to be -

```
{\"name\":\"$name\",\"projectId\":\"10034\"}
```

I want to the output to be -

```
{\"name\":\"abc\",\"projectId\":\"10034\"}
```

How can we place the variable value inside ""(double quotes) in this case.

Comment: Maybe this would help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113413/how-do-i-concatenate-strings-and-variables-in-powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want string interpolation, you have to use double quotes. For using double quotes inside double quotes , you have to escape them with `(backquote).

```
$name="abc"
$json = "{\`"name\`":\`"$name\`",\`"projectId\`":\`"10034\`"}"
$json
```

The output is:

```
{\"name\":\"abc\",\"projectId\":\"10034\"}
```