# Why does using single quotes with variables yield error "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument"?

Tags: string, powershell, concatenation, variable-assignment

I have an variable: `$a = sfd`. If I use `New-Item '1'$a`, then it will yield this error:

```
New-Item: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'sdf'.
```

But if I use `New-Item "1$a"` then it works. According to [How do I concatenate strings and variables in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32455290/3416774) both two methods should work. Do you know why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `'1'$a` is seen as two separate arguments and the [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item) cmdlet has only 1 positional parameter ([`-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item#-path)) unlike e.g. `Write-Host` which accepts multiple positional parameters:

```
$a = sfd
Write-Host '1'$a
1 sfd
```

(Note that the arguments are separated with a space in the displayed results)

There are several other ways to concatenate strings in PowerShell aside from `"1$a"`, as e.g. `New-Item ('1' + $a)`. For more information see [Everything you wanted to know about variable substitution in strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-string-substitutions)

Answer (score 1):

No clue why this is accepted by the Write-Host cmdlet in the linked example (probably because the cmdlet accepts an object). If I use it standalone (`'1'$a`) I receive the following error:

```
Unexpected token '$a' in expression or statement.
```

So even it will work with some cmdlets, I would never use the `'1'$a` syntax to join a string. Instead, use one of the following options:

- `"1$a"`
- `('1 ' + $a)`
- `('1{0}' -f $a)`

The last example uses a format string and is useful when you have to concat multiple variables into a string to increase the readability. See: [Understanding PowerShell and Basic String Formatting](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-powershell-and-basic-string-formatting/?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203)

Comment: as for the first method, is there a way to add an immediate character after the variable, but doesn't make PowerShell mistaken for a different variable? I try `1($a)2` but the result is `1(sdf)2`

Comment: Yes, you can use a backtick: "1$a`2"