# PowerShell: apply command to multiple files

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I am fairly new to PowerShell and I'm struggling to see what's wrong with the following command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*Q1 2016.pdf" | For.\pdftk A={$_.name} B={$_.name -replace 'Q1 2016.pdf','Q1 2016-quad.pdf'} cat A1-3 B1 A5-end output {$_.name -replace 'Q1 2016.pdf','Q1 2016-final.pdf'}
```

I get the following error:

```
pdftk.exe : The command parameter was already specified.
At line:1 char:40
+ ... 2016.pdf" | .\pdftk A={$_.name} B={$_.name -replace 'Q1 2016.pdf','Q1 ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterSpecifiedAlready
```

However, when I run a single command call, it works fine:

```
.\pdftk A='myfile-Q1 2016.pdf' B='myfile-Q1 2016-quad.pdf' cat A1-3 B1 A5-end output 'myfile-final.pdf'
```

Any thoughts of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run an EXE file in PowerShell with parameters with spaces and quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673967/how-to-run-an-exe-file-in-powershell-with-parameters-with-spaces-and-quotes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it should be like this:

`Get-ChildItem -Filter “*Q1 2016.pdf” | ForEach {.\pdftk A=$($_.name) B=$($_.name -replace ‘Q1 2016.pdf’,’Q1 2016-quad.pdf’) cat A1-3 B1 A5-end output $($_.name -replace ‘Q1 2016.pdf’,’Q1 2016-final.pdf’)}`

Somehow, the following does not work, but the above does:

`Get-ChildItem -Filter “*Q1 2016.pdf” | ForEach {.\pdftk A={$_.name} B={$_.name -replace ‘Q1 2016.pdf’,’Q1 2016-quad.pdf’} cat A1-3 B1 A5-end output {$_.name -replace ‘Q1 2016.pdf’,’Q1 2016-final.pdf’}}`

Comment: this may be attempting to explain why the $($variable) syntax is needed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615676/what-does-variablename-mean-in-powershell