# Output variable name to user

Tags: powershell

When a parameter is not supplied to my script, I want to include the parameter/variable name as a string in the `Write-Error` message:

```
$RequiredArgs = @($Arg1, $Arg2, $Arg3, $Arg4)

foreach ($Arg in $RequiredArgs) {
    if (!($Arg)) {
        Write-Error "Argument: $Arg is required."
        throw
    }
}
```

This currently outputs `Argument:    is required.`. I have tried quoting the variable name:

```
Write-Error "Argument: "$Arg" is required."
```

But this shows the error: `Write-Error: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument ' is required.`

Is there a way to output the variable name, even if the parameter is not set?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use **single** quotes:

```
Write-Error 'Argument: "$Arg" is required.'
```

---

Consider to use the **Mandatory** parameter attribute to specify required paramter in your script:

```
Param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Arg1
)

Write-Host "Hello $Arg1"
```

Now if you try to execute the script and omit the parameter you will get prompted for them:
[image]

Comment: This outputs: `Argument: "$Arg" is required.` When: `Argument: "$Arg2" is required` or `$Arg3`, `$Arg4` is expected?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what Martin has already mentioned you can do this -

```
$RequiredArgs = @($Arg1, $Arg2, $Arg3, $Arg4)

foreach ($Arg in $RequiredArgs) {
    if (!($Arg)) {
        Write-Error "Argument: $($Arg) is required."
        throw
    }
}
```

The `$($Arg)` syntax helps with evaluating the expression inside `$Arg`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615676/what-does-variablename-mean-in-powershell) SO link for details.