# How do I concatenate values in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to Resolve some DNS records using PowerShell.  All of the Resolve-DnsName methods work below with the exception of the one where I try to append "owa." to the beginning of the domain name.  The latest error I get is "*cannot validate argument on parameter name*". I have tried various combinations with no luck (i.e. owa.$Domain.Name).  What is the proper way to concatenate the values to achieve a successful DNS resolution?

```
$Domain = New-Object System.Object
$Domain | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name MXRecord -value $MXQuery
$Domain | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Name -value "mydomain.com"
$MXQueryRecord = Resolve-DnsName $Domain.Name -type MX -Server 8.8.8.8
$OWAQuery = Resolve-DnsName $("owa.")-$($Domain.Name) -type CNAME -Server 8.8.8.8
$TXTQuery = Resolve-DnsName $Domain.Name -type TXT -Server 8.8.8.8
$NSQuery = Resolve-DnsName $Domain.Name -type NS -Server 8.8.8.8

$Queries =$($MXQuery,$OWAQuery,$TXTQuery,$NSQuery)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Use `(...)` to pass an expression's value / command's output as a command argumen**t:

```
Resolve-DnsName ("owa." + $Domain.Name) -type CNAME -Server 8.8.8.8
```

Note: [`$(...)`, the subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#subexpression-operator--), is only needed if what you're trying to pass comprises *multiple* statements. [`@(...)`, the array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#array-subexpression-operator--), is only needed if you need to guarantee that the output is treated as an *array* even if only a single object is output.

**`(...)`, `$(...)`, `@(...)`** have the **advantage of working with *any* data type**, not just strings.

Alternatively, **if what you're passing is a *string* value** (as in this case), you can use **string expansion (interpolation)**, as shown in [Drako's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53870850/45375).

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `$("owa.")-$($Domain.Name)`

is parsed as *two* arguments by PowerShell:

- Subexpression `$("owa.")`, which evaluates to string literal `owa.`
- Expandable string `-$($Domain.Name)`, which evaluates to `-<domain-name>` (evaluation as an expandable string means that is evaluated the same way it would if you explicitly double-quoted that token (`"-$($Domain.Name)"`)).

It's not always obvious **when PowerShell breaks a compound token into *multiple* arguments**; the behavior is summarized [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6467).
To learn about **how unquoted tokens are parsed as arguments in general**, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375).

Note that if you had *double-quoted* your *entire token* (`"$("owa.")-$($Domain.Name)"`), your command would have worked too (but there'd be no need to embed a string *literal* via `$(...)`).
**To learn more about *expandable strings* (string interpolation)**, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49031158/45375).

Comment: you don't need concatenation that just unnecessary consumes extra (even very little in this case) CPU power.

Comment: @Drako fairly certain a subexpression is slower, but none of this matters when dealing with strings of small sets

Comment: @Drako: I doubt that that's a real-world concern, and, like TheIncorrigible1, my guess is that string interpolation is _slower_. That said, string interpolation is a viable alternative in this case, so I've added a link to your answer. I've chosen to showcase `(...)`, because it works with _any_ type of argument, not just _strings_.

Comment: I have not done such tests for this in PowerShell so will not argue :) . (have done similar tests in C++ and Python; there my approach makes less CPU instructions, so I assume same here but obviously my guess can be wrong as PS parses strings differently :) )

Comment: @Drako: I took a quick look, but let me preface the next comment by saying that this won't matter in the real world, and **the method you pick should _not_ be chosen based on performance considerations - instead, decide based on data-type needs and readability**.

Comment: @Drako: On my single-core W10 VM with Windows PowerShell v5.1, expandable strings (`"owa.-$($Domain.Name)"`) are _marginally_ slower - again, it won't matter in the real world. Test command (averages 100,000 runs): `$domain = @{ Name = 'example.org' }; Time-Command { Write-Output ("owa." + $Domain.Name) }, { Write-Output "owa.-$($Domain.Name)" }
 -Count 1e5`. The `Time-Command` function can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/9e1f13978620b09ab2d15da5535d1b27).

Comment: Thanks for info. I'll take it into account and its not that weird knowing that PS has very complex string parsing mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

Try to write it like this

```
$OWAQuery = Resolve-DnsName "owa.-$($Domain.Name)" -type CNAME -Server 8.8.8.8
```

(if I correctly understood that it should look as: owa.-somedomainname; because dash seems extra so just remove it if unnecessary)