# Powershell - Object reference from XML

Tags: xml, powershell, object

I need to determine where to load "Company" form a configuration file.

```
<config>
  <username>$env:username</username>
  <company>$User.Company</company>
</config>
```

After loading the config file:

```
$ConfigFile=[xml](Get-Content $ConfigFileName)
$ConfigFile.config.Company
```

It returns:

```
$User.Company
```

"$User" is another object, where $User.Company equals:

```
ACME Company
```

I had tried:

```
$Company=$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($ConfigFile.config.Company)
```

But that only expands "$User", not "$User.Company".

How do I set $Company to $Config.config.Company that will result in a string "ACME Company"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString()` performs the **same kind of string expansion (interpolation)** that PowerShell implicitly performs on **`"..."`, i.e., *double-quoted* strings**.

Inside a double-quoted string, **expanding an *expression* such as `$User.Company`** - as opposed to a mere *variable reference* (e.g., `$User`) - **requires that the expression be enclosed in `$(...)`** - otherwise, as you've experienced `$User`, is expanded *by itself*, with `.Company` being considered a *literal*.

<sup>See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49031158/45375) for an overview of PowerShell's string-expansion rules.</sup>

You have two options:

- enclose the string's *content* in `$(...)` before passing it to `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString()`
- use `Invoke-Expression` instead, but note that [Invoke-Expression should generally be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/)

That said, ***both* solutions ultimately blindly execute any expressions / statements contained in the string, so you should only do that with input you *trust***.

To put it all together:

```
# Sample $User object
$User = [pscustomobject] @{ Company = 'ACME Company' }

# Read the XML
$ConfigFile = [xml] '<config>
<username>$env:username</username>
<company>$User.Company</company>
</config>'

# Pass the element value of interest to $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString
# after enclosing it in '$(...)' via -f, the string-formatting operator.
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString('$({0})' -f $ConfigFile.config.Company)
```

The above yields:

```
ACME Company
```