# Loop through an array of databases to run a SQL query against database

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run the same SQL query against a number of databases and output the result to a separate text file for each database. What I'm doing so far has issues with the output file name. When I ammend filename to just use `C:\TEMP\usersoutput_$Num.txt`, it puts everything in to just one file. Here is my code:

```
$DBArray = @("DataBase1","DataBase2","DataBase3","DataBase4","DataBase5")
$Num = 0

foreach ($element in $DBArray) {
    (Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "...." -ServerInstance Server2 -Database $DBArray[$Num] -Verbose
    ) *>> C:\TEMP\usersoutput_$DBArray[$Num].txt |
    foreach {$Num = $Num + 1}
}
```

Where am I going wrong with this; is this the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PowerShell to properly parse anything more complex than a variable name inside a string, put the expression in `$()`:

```
C:\TEMP\usersoutput_$($DBArray[$Num]).txt
```

But since you are already using a `foreach` loop, you don't need the `$Num` index variable:

```
foreach ($db in $DBArray) {
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "...." -ServerInstance "Server2" -Database $db -Verbose |
    Out-File "C:\TEMP\usersoutput_$db.txt"
}
```

or:

```
"DataBase1","DataBase2","DataBase3","DataBase4","DataBase5" | foreach {
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "...." -ServerInstance "Server2" -Database $_ -Verbose |
    Out-File "C:\TEMP\usersoutput_$_.txt"
}
```

Comment: I knew it was a lot more simple, working for me now :-)

Answer (score 2):

1. When you are already using a `foreach` loop, you do not need to use an increment counter.
2. If you are using a `foreach` loop, you need to access the elements inside the loop using the variable `$element` and not `$DBArray`.
3. Make use of `$($element)` to [evaluate the expression inside the variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615676/what-does-variablename-mean-in-expandable-strings-in-powershell).

Below will work for you -

```
$DBArray = @("DataBase1","DataBase2","DataBase3","DataBase4","DataBase5")
foreach ($element in $DBArray)
{
    (Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "...." -ServerInstance Server2 -Database $element -Verbose) *>> C:\TEMP\usersoutput_$($element).txt
}
```