# Formatting numbers in PowerShell to remove the "," for numbers > 1k?

Tags: powershell, formatting, numbers, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I read the page about formatting [PS Formatting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692795.aspx), but my needs are a little different.

If I use numeric formatting for numbers bigger than 1000 I will always get something like this:

```
$x = 1000
"{0:N2}" -f $x
 = 1,000.00
```

But what I need is: 1000.00 since I can't work with commas here.

So how do I make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the `N` format specifier.  Use `F` (fixed-point) instead:

```
C:\PS> "{0:F2}" -f 1000
1000.00
```

See this [MSDN topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on all the standard .NET number format specifiers.

Comment: The funny part is that it depends on system language. So for US it's for example 1000.86 and germany its 1000,86 using the same formatting. is there a formatting which switches to US?

Comment: ahh found your other answer regarding this :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379514/powershell-formatting-values-in-another-culture

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you need.

```
'{0:f2}' -f 1000
```