# PowerShell date format not accepted in SQL

Tags: date, datetime, powershell, environment-variables

I'm having kind of a strange problem. When the server's `Region and Language` settings is set to `English (United States)` there are no issues with objects containing the date and time. But when I change it to my countries local `Dutch (Belgium)` I am experiencing problems in some of my PowerShell scripts.

Is there somewhere a variable in PowerShell that needs to be set to fix this? Or do I have to default to English date formats on the server all the time?

We use for example the `SQL module` provided by Don Jones for filling up an SQL database. This line generates an error when it's set to Dutch, but not when it's set to English:

```
if ($properties[$property] -eq 'datetime2') { [datetime]$prop = $result.GetDateTime($result.GetOrdinal($property)) }
```

The only thing I do to retrieve the date is [Get-Date](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849887.aspx) without anything special. And it generates this error when set to `Dutch (Belgium)`:

```
Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from char
acter string."
```

I've experienced the same problem when generating stuff for [Excel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel) sheets. It also complains about the date time format.

Comment: See this thread once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379514/powershell-formatting-values-in-another-culture

Comment: Thank you Rahul, I knew about this workaround. But why isn't it just accepting `[datetime]` in the same way that `Get-Date` is used? It should normally work without adding extra functions, no?

Comment: AFAIK, the default has to to be `en-us` format. are you just trying to format the result of `get-date`?

Comment: I've found a quick workaround,without having to change my `Region and Language` settings by using `Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss"` instead of just `Get-Date`. Then it works for the SQL module. I guess it just expects to receive this format and the Belgian format is different and for that reason will not be accepted.

Comment: That's what I was exactly talking about and that's why asked you whether are you just trying to format the result of get-date in above comment. Good job :)

Comment: Got it now, but didn't get it at first (if that is a sentence at all :P). This solution of pre-formatting works out just fine for me. Thank you Rahul :)

Comment: You may like to post the solution as answer, if in case it helps future readers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For exporting information like `DateTime` fields to SQL, the default language setting is `English (United States)`.

So when your `Region and Language` settings are different from the default for SQL, being: `English (United States)` <> `Dutch (Belgium)`, you should use the following format in your code to comply to the English defaults:

```
Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
$_.whenCreated.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

Another solution is to change the default language for input in SQL Express 2014:

1. Right click the server instance and select `Properties > Advanced`
2. Change `Default language` to `Dutch` (or what you use)
3. Confirm with `Ok`
4. Still in `SQL Management Studio` go to `Security > Logins` (below Databases)
5. Double click your `user name` and select `Dutch` below as `Default language`
6. Restart `SQL Management Studio` and you should be good to go

**Result:**
When you use the CmdLet `Get-Date` in your PowerShell code it will work as designed when transferring data to SQL. The system language for SQL and Windows is still English but the formatting used is Dutch.

Comment: Just confirmed this, I noticed it wasn't marked as an answer so I just wanted to post that this does work and resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I use this for Datetime2 in SQL Server.

```
Function Get-Datetime2([datetime]$Date = $(Get-Date) ) {
    $DT = Get-Date -Date $Date
    [string]$DateTime2 =  $DT.Month.ToString() + '/'
    [string]$DateTime2 += $DT.Day.ToString() + '/'
    [string]$DateTime2 += $DT.Year.ToString() + ' '
    [string]$DateTime2 += $DT.TimeOfDay.ToString()
    return $DateTime2
}

Get-Datetime2
```

returns something that looks like this.

```
3/12/2018 03:04:34.7496659
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already use Don Jones' module you may already be familiar with type-extension through the *.types.ps1xml... There should be one in his module too, if I remember correctly.

When adding the following type declaration,

```
  <Type>
    <Name>System.DateTime</Name>
    <Members>
      <ScriptMethod>
        <Name>ToString</Name>
        <Script>
          $(Get-Date $This -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
        </Script>
      </ScriptMethod>
    </Members>
  </Type>
```

You basically override System.DateTime's ToString() method to the format needed by a standard SQL Server installation.

This way you can make sure that every time you load the SQL module dates they are being formatted the right way.