# Powershell Sort of Strings with Underscores

Tags: sorting, powershell, stringcomparer

The following list does not sort properly (IMHO):

```
$a = @( 'ABCZ', 'ABC_', 'ABCA' )
$a | sort
ABC_
ABCA
ABCZ
```

My handy ASCII chart and Unicode C0 Controls and Basic Latin chart 
have the underscore (low line) with an ordinal of 95 (U+005F).  This is a higher number than the capital letters A-Z.  Sort should have put the string ending with an underscore last.

Get-Culture is en-US

The next set of commands does what I expect:

```
$a = @( 'ABCZ', 'ABC_', 'ABCA' )
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $al = $a
$al.Sort( [System.StringComparer]::Ordinal )
$al
ABCA
ABCZ
ABC_
```

Now I create an ANSI encoded file containing those same 3 strings:

```
Get-Content -Encoding Byte data.txt
65 66 67 90 13 10  65 66 67 95 13 10  65 66 67 65 13 10
$a = Get-Content data.txt
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $al = $a
$al.Sort( [System.StringComparer]::Ordinal )
$al
ABC_
ABCA
ABCZ
```

Once more the string containing the underscore/lowline is not sorted correctly.  What am I missing?

---

Edit:

Let's reference this example #4:

```
'A' -lt '_'
False
[char] 'A' -lt [char] '_'
True
```

Seems like both statements should be False or both should be True.  I'm comparing strings in the first statement, and then comparing the Char type.  A string is merely a collection of Char types so I think the two comparison operations should be equivalent.

And now for example #5:

```
Get-Content -Encoding Byte data.txt
65 66 67 90 13 10  65 66 67 95 13 10  65 66 67 65 13 10
$a = Get-Content data.txt
$b = @( 'ABCZ', 'ABC_', 'ABCA' )
$a[0] -eq $b[0]; $a[1] -eq $b[1]; $a[2] -eq $b[2];
True
True
True
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $al = $a
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $bl = $b
$al[0] -eq $bl[0]; $al[1] -eq $bl[1]; $al[2] -eq $bl[2];
True
True
True
$al.Sort( [System.StringComparer]::Ordinal )
$bl.Sort( [System.StringComparer]::Ordinal )
$al
ABC_
ABCA
ABCZ
$bl
ABCA
ABCZ
ABC_
```

The two ArrayList contain the same strings, but are sorted differently.  Why?

Comment: I think what you are missing is that you are expecting non-standard responses from Windows. It has always prioritized symbols before letters, just look at the file system. Make files with those names, sort by name, and it will sort them the same way with ABC_ being first.

Comment: [String sorting is not done by ASCII code any more.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/18/134051.aspx)

Comment: Also as far as I can tell the weirdness with the second part has something to do with `ArrayList`. Using a strongly typed `String.Collections.Generic.List[string]` sorts as expected. Also, using an `string[]` sorts as expected with `Array::Sort`, but `object[]` does not.

Comment: You'll also have to confirm what `Get-Content data.txt` actually returns.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the use of `String.Collections.Generic.List[string]` @mikez.  It works and if you want to reply I'll accept it as an answer.  I just wished I understood the difference between my use of Get-Contents and definiting the array inline (see example #5).

Comment: Hmmm... I thought it could have been because one of the `ArrayList` instances was actually an `IListWrapper` or some other "hidden" difference (even though I can see the simple creation step), but if you apply `$aa=$al.ToArray` and sort using `[System.Array]::Sort($aa, [System.StringComparer]::Ordinal )` (and equivalently for `$bl -> $ba` then they still sort differently!

Comment: There is something "special" about `$a`. Even though each individual element has type `String`, you can't `.CopyTo` a `String` array!

Comment: And when you construct a 6 `Object` array and `.CopyTo` it both `$a` and `$b`, `sort` fails to want to compare some items...

Comment: Posted to Microsoft Connect as a bug. See https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedbackdetail/view/974422

Comment: Seems like adding a switch to allow 'ordinal' sorting to the `sort-object` cmdlet would be the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many moons later, let me attempt a comprehensive summary:

**By design**:

- **PowerShell's [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) does *not* perform *ordinal* sorting** of strings (the latter being based strictly on the Unicode [*code points*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) (sometimes still loosely, but incorrectly referred to  as "ASCII values") of the characters in the string).
- Instead, like the underlying .NET runtime, it **performs *culture-specific* sorting based on *linguistic* rules** by default.

  - Note: **In [*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) v7.1+ / *.NET 5+* the sorting rules *changed***, due to the latter's move to the [ICU](https://icu.unicode.org/) libraries even on Windows (which had previously used [NLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/national-language-support)) - see [.NET globalization and ICU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu)

    - The resulting changes, notably due to sorting `_` before `.`, spurred complaints, because it changes long-established behavior in the context of *file-system*-related operations - see [GitHub issue #14757](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14757#issuecomment-1664221189).
  - Also, a notable difference is that PowerShell, unlike .NET, is generally case-*insensitive* by default, requiring the `-CaseSensitive` switch as an opt-in to case-sensitivity.

    - In other words: `Sort-Object` uses [`[StringComparer]::CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) by default, and  `-CaseSensitive` changes that to [`[StringComparer]::CurrentCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.StringComparer.CurrentCulture)
    - `Sort-Object`'s `-Culture` parameter allows you to change the cultural context *ad hoc*; use `-Culture 127` to choose the [*invariant* culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) (which PowerShell uses *by default* in many contexts - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375)).
  - Unfortunately, as of PowerShell (Core) 7.4.x, unlike with direct use of .NET APIs, you can NOT make `Sort-Object` perform *ordinal* sorting.

    - [GitHub issue #9348](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9348) asks for a number of cmdlets, including `Sort-Object` to be enhanced so as to support ordinal sorting on demand, along with an associated RFC, https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-RFC/pull/167. Unfortunately, activity has stalled quite a while ago.

---

**Unexpectedly**:

- As for **why sorting the array resulting from `$a = Get-Content data.txt`  vs. an *array literal* behaves differently** - [user4003407's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33704502/45375) explains the technical underpinnings in detail, but let me attempt a pragmatic summary:

  - Behind the scenes, **PowerShell situationally uses [`[psobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSObject) wrappers around .NET objects, which are meant to be *invisible helper objects*, but, unfortunately, they aren't *always* invisible and sometimes cause *unexpected behavior***.

    - This recurring problem is discussed in [GitHub issue #5579](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5579).
  - Notably, objects output from cmdlets (such as [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)) are *invariably* `[psobject]`-wrapped.
  - Thus, when such `[psobject]`-wrapped objects are implicitly collected in a regular PowerShell array - as happens when you capture the lines of a text file being *streamed* by `Get-Content` in a variable, for instance - you'll end up with an `[object[]`-typed array whose elements happen to be `[psobject]` instances (which happen to wrap `[string]` instances).
  - By contrast, if you capture an array of *string literals* in a variable - e.g. `$a = @( 'ABCZ', 'ABC_', 'ABCA' )` - the resulting `[object[]]`-typed array has `[string]` elements, i.e. *no* `[psobject]` wrappers are involved.
  - When an `[object[]]`-typed array or *non-generic* array-like type such as [`System.Collections.ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ArrayList) is used, the above distinction *matters*:

    - Only if the original array's elements are `[string]`-typed does a sorting qualifier such as `[System.StringComparer]::Ordinal` matter; otherwise, this qualifier is *ignored*, and comparison for sorting is delegated to whatever type the elements happen to be:
    - `[psobject]` happens to implement the [`IComparable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable) interface itself, and it effectively delegates to the `[string]` type's implementation behind the scenes, albeit using the latter's *default* behavior - which is the culture-sensitive, case-sensitive sorting (`[StringComparer]::CurrentCulture)`).
      This behavior is counter-intuitive, but cannot be changed for fear of breaking backward compatibility - see [GitHub issue #14829](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14829) for discussion.
    - For a given array (list) `$a`, a simple test as to whether an element is `[psobject]`-wrapped is `$a[0] -is [psobject]`, for instance.
  - To provide **simplified examples**:

    ```bash
    # == OK: Elements are NOT [psobject]-wrapped
    $a = '_', 'A'
    [Array]::Sort($a, [StringComparer]::Ordinal)
    $a # -> 'A', '_'  - ORDINAL sorting
       # (Code point of 'A' is 0x41 (65), of '_' is 0x5f (95))

    [System.Collections.ArrayList] $al = '_', 'A'
    $al.Sort([StringComparer]::Ordinal)
    $al # -> 'A', '_' - ORDINAL sorting

    # == !! BROKEN: Elements ARE [psobject]-wrapped, therefore
    #    !! [StringComparer]::Ordinal is *ignored*

    # !! Using Write-Output causes the array elements to be [psobject]-wrapped,
    # !! as Get-Content does.
    $a = Write-Output '_', 'A'
    # !! [StringComparer]::Ordinal is IGNORED, due to [psobject] wrappers.
    [Array]::Sort($a, [StringComparer]::Ordinal)
    $a # -> 'A', '_' - quiet fallback to the default, [StringComparer]::CurrentCulture

    # !! Using Write-Output causes the array elements to be [psobject]-wrapped
    [System.Collections.ArrayList] $al = Write-Output '_', 'A'
    # !! [StringComparer]::Ordinal is IGNORED, due to [psobject] wrappers.
    $al.Sort([StringComparer]::Ordinal)
    $al # -> 'A', '_' - quiet fallback to the default, [StringComparer]::CurrentCulture
    ```
  - **Workaround**:

    - **Casting** an `[object[]]` array whose elements are `[psobject]`-wrapped **to a *specific type*** - such as `[string[]]` in the case at hand - implicitly *discards* the `[psobject]` wrappers:

      ```bash
      # The [string[]] cast implicitly discards the [psobject] wrappers
      # in the process of creating a *strongly typed* array.
      [string[]] $a = Write-Output '_', 'A'
      [Array]::Sort($a, [StringComparer]::Ordinal)
      $a # -> 'A', '_'  - ORDINAL sorting, as requested.
      ```
- As for **PowerShell's *comparison operators* and the inconsistent `[char]` handling**:

  - PowerShell's [comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators) such as `-eq` and `-lt`:

    - With **`[string]` instances**, like `Sort-Object`, **comparison operators use *linguistic* rules, however based on the [*invariant*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) culture** rather than on the *current* culture (the latter being reflected in `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture` / `Get-Culture`, `$PSCulture`).

      - While the distinction between the *current* and the *invariant* culture will often *not* matter in practice, it definitely *can*.
      - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375) for a comprehensive discussion of the contexts in which PowerShell uses one or the other.
    - By contrast, **`[char]` instances are compared by their Unicode *code points*, albeit *inconsistently***, depending on the specific comparison operator used; note that PowerShell has *no* `[char]` *literal* representation, so a `[char]` *cast* is always required:

      - `-eq` (aka `-ieq`) and its case-*sensitive* variant, `-ceq`, as well as its *negated* variants (`-ne` (aka `-ine`) and `-cne`) *do* take *case* into account, as implied / requested: If case-*insensitivity* is required, the operands are first normalized via [`.ToUpperInvariant()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Char.ToUpperInvariant) behind the scenes:

        ```bash
        # Equivalent to:
        # [uint16] [char]::ToUpperInvariant('A') -eq [uint16] [char]::ToUpperInvariant('a')
        # Casting to [uint16] returns a [char] instance's Unicode code point.
        [char] 'A' -eq [char] 'a' # -> $true
        ```
      - By contrast, `-lt` (less than) and `-gt` (greater than) and its variants unexpectedly *ignore* case-sensitivity:

        ```bash
        # !! Unexpectedly ALSO $true
        # !! Equivalent to [uint16] [char] 'A' -lt [uint16] [char] 'a'
        # !! i.e. NO case normalization is performed.  
        [char] 'A' -lt [char] 'a' # ditto for -ilt and (as expected) for -clt
        ```

        - This problematic inconsistency is the subject of [GitHub issue #18659](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18659).

Comment: Wow!  This will take a (very long) bit for me to parse.  I very much appreciate all the detail you put into your response and hope it helps many people in the future.

Answer (score 3):

In many cases PowerShell wrap/unwrap objects in/from `PSObject`. In most cases it is done transparently, and you does not even notice this, but in your case it is what cause your trouble.

```
$a='ABCZ', 'ABC_', 'ABCA'
$a|Set-Content data.txt
$b=Get-Content data.txt

[Type]::GetTypeArray($a).FullName
# System.String
# System.String
# System.String
[Type]::GetTypeArray($b).FullName
# System.Management.Automation.PSObject
# System.Management.Automation.PSObject
# System.Management.Automation.PSObject
```

As you can see, object returned from `Get-Content` are wrapped in `PSObject`, that prevent `StringComparer` from seeing underlying strings and compare them properly. Strongly typed string collecting can not store `PSObject`s, so PowerShell will unwrap strings to store them in strongly typed collection, that allows `StringComparer` to see strings and compare them properly.

## Edit:

First of all, when you write that `$a[1].GetType()` or that `$b[1].GetType()` you does not call .NET methods, but PowerShell methods, which normally call .NET methods on wrapped object. Thus you can not get real type of objects this way. Even more, them can be overridden, consider this code:

```
$c='String'|Add-Member -Type ScriptMethod -Name GetType -Value {[int]} -Force -PassThru
$c.GetType().FullName
# System.Int32
```

Let us call .NET methods thru reflection:

```
$GetType=[Object].GetMethod('GetType')
$GetType.Invoke($c,$null).FullName
# System.String
$GetType.Invoke($a[1],$null).FullName
# System.String
$GetType.Invoke($b[1],$null).FullName
# System.String
```

Now we get real type for `$c`, but it says that type of `$b[1]` is `String` not `PSObject`. As I say, in most cases unwrapping done transparently, so you see wrapped `String` and not `PSObject` itself. One particular case when it does not happening is that: when you pass array, then array elements are not unwrapped. So, let us add additional level of indirection here:

```
$Invoke=[Reflection.MethodInfo].GetMethod('Invoke',[Type[]]([Object],[Object[]]))
$Invoke.Invoke($GetType,($a[1],$null)).FullName
# System.String
$Invoke.Invoke($GetType,($b[1],$null)).FullName
# System.Management.Automation.PSObject
```

Now, as we pass `$b[1]` as part of array, we can see real type of it: `PSObject`. Although, I prefer to use `[Type]::GetTypeArray` instead.

About `StringComparer`: [as you can see](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/stringcomparer.cs,91), when not both compared objects are strings, then `StringComparer` rely on `IComparable.CompareTo` for comparison. And [`PSObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.management.automation.psobject.aspx) implement `IComparable` interface, so that sorting will be done according to `PSObject` `IComparable` implementation.

Comment: I think your on to something.  But the sort does rearrange the PSObject items, just not as I would expect.  $a[1].GetType().Name and $b[1].GetType().Name both return "String".  Can you point me to documentation with more details on arrays, PSObjects, and how the StringComparer might work when presented PSObjects?  Thanks.

Comment: @bretth I update my answer. Sorry, I can not point you to good documentation about that. Great part of my PowerShell knowledge obtained thru experimentation and digging with ILSpy. IMHO, PowerShell really lacking documentation about many internal parts.

Comment: This may also be related?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44731470/powershell-sorting-string-objects-with-a-special-character

Answer (score 0):

Windows uses Unicode, not ASCII, so what you're seeing is the Unicode sort order for en-US.  The general rules for sorting are:

1. numbers, then lowercase and uppercase intermixed
2. Special characters occur before numbers.

Extending your example,

```
$a = @( 'ABCZ', 'ABC_', 'ABCA', 'ABC4', 'abca' )

$a | sort-object
ABC_
ABC4
abca
ABCA
ABCZ
```

Comment: But the OP is explicitly asking for `Ordinal` order, and each individual Object in `$a` reports a type of `String`, but they don't fit in a `String` array. So, yes, we're getting the default Unicode ordering on `Object` instead of the requested `Ordinal` ordering. But why?

Comment: Unicode string sorting can be seen in practice here: http://minaret.info/test/sort.msp

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and the sort is as expected:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $al = [String[]] $a
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this....  I will admit it's ugly but it works. I would create a function if this is something you need to do on a regular basis.

$a = @( 'ABCZ', 'ABC_', 'ABCA', 'ab1z' )
$ascii = @()

foreach ($item in $a)
    {
    $string = "" 
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $item.length; $i++)
        {
        $char = [int] [char] $item[$i]
        $string += "$char;"
        }

```
$ascii += $string
}
```

$b = @()

foreach ($item in $ascii | Sort-Object)
    {
    $string = ""
    $array = $item.Split(";")
    foreach ($char in $array)
        {
        $string += [char] [int] $char
        }

```
$b += $string
}
```

$a
$b

ABCA
ABCZ
ABC_