# Problems getting correct output in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying a to make this PowerShell script that would ask for the user to input a service name, run through `Get-Service`, and show the result to the user.

For example, if the user was to enter `vmtools` it would show:

```
Status      Name      DisplayName
------      ----      -----------
Running     vmtools   VMware Tools
```

This is my code:

```
Write-host "Enter Service name"
$ServiceName = read-host
$Result = get-service $ServiceName
Write-Output "$Result"
```

However, it only outputs: `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because when you add quotation marks around certain types of variables, it outputs the variable type, not the actual contents of the variable. Therefore, removing quotation marks on the variable output will fix your problem. Replace your last line with this:

```
Write-Output $Result
```

Comment: It doesn't output a _type_ - it does output the _contents_ of the variable, albeit in _stringified form_, via the type's `.ToString()` method - and only if a given type doesn't override the default implementation of that method does it result in a string containing the _type name_. A counterexample is `$Result = Get-Date; "$Result"`

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr**

```bash
$Result # Implicitly outputs $Result - no need for Write-Output or "..."
```

---

Unlike POSIX-like shells (Unix):

- PowerShell **never *requires* `"..."` around a variable reference** such as `$Result`.

  - In fact, **doing so converts the variable to a *string*** - which may or may not be the intent.
- If you *do* want a *string*, **using `"..."` around a variable reference *often* - but *not necessarily* - results in a *different* representation than when printing to the *terminal* (console)**.
- If the **object is to be processed further, pass it on *as-is***, otherwise you'll lose the benefits of PowerShell's object orientation.

**PowerShell passes *objects* around** - which represents its great evolutionary leap from traditional shells - and **only on (a) *output to the terminal* or sending output *to a file with `>`* (`Out-File`) / `Out-String` or (b) *inside `"..."`* or (c) *when applying `.ToString()`* are these objects *stringified***:

- (a) uses PowerShell's default formatting system, which allows you to define custom representations for any .NET type (with several representations predefined); e.g., outputting hashtable `@{ one = 1; two = 2}` yields a pretty-printed 2-column layout; see [`Get-Help about_format.ps1xml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml).
- (b) and (c) *bypass* PowerShell's default formatting:

  - (c), directly calling each object's **`.ToString()` method** - **can range from** a **virtually meaningless type name-only representation** (as in your case, or as in `@{ one = 1; two = 2 }.ToString()`, which yields `System.Collection.Hashtable`) **to a culture-*sensitive* representation** (e.g., `(Get-Date '2017-01-01').ToString()` yields `1/1/17 12:00:00 AM` on a US-English system) - depending on whatever the given type supports.
    For the **[.NET *base types*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks), the `.ToString()` representation is the same as PowerShell's default formatting**.
  - **(b)'s rules (implicit stringification inside `"..."`) are *similar*** to (c)'s except that **PowerShell by design seeks a culture-*invariant* representation** *where supported* - for details, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375).