# Non Uniform System.DateTime.Now default formats in C# and PowerShell

Tags: c#, .net, file, powershell, datetime

Why it is like we get different DateTime formats (*especially for date separators slash vs hyphen*) without using any custom formats when printed on the console and written to a file.

Even when using the same Dotnet's `System.DateTime.Now`, I am seeing the difference in the output of C# vs PowerShell.

**Following are my observations for C# and Powershell:**

*C# - On Console*

> 06-08-2018 02:01:11 AM

*C# - written to a file*

> 06-08-2018 02:02:32 PM

*PowerShell - [System.DateTime]::Now - On Console*

> 06 August 2018 01:54:45 AM

*PowerShell - [System.DateTime]::Now.ToLocalTime() - On Console*

> 06 August 2018 01:54:53 AM

*PowerShell - Get-Date - On Console*

> 06 August 2018 01:54:57 AM

*PowerShell - [System.DateTime]::Now - written to a file*

> 08/06/2018 01:46:35

**I am mostly curious about when written to a file case of both C# and PowerShell as observed in the same system.**

*One more point to be noted* - I have also seen the C#'s hyphen getting changed into slash on a different system when running the same exe. I am not sure why this happens and due to this it caused some exceptions. I had to use explicit DateTime format to overcome this problem.

**Are there any best practices when dealing with DateTime formats?**

======================== **UPDATE** ====================================

As per suggested by @mjwills:

I found that when explicitly using the Tostring() in PowerShell, the behavior becomes consistent in C# and Powershell even if written to a file through PowerShell.

```
[System.DateTime]::Now.ToString()
```

Comment: To avoid default, use  Now.ToString(your format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An implicit call to **`.ToString()`** is made when you pass a `System.DateTime` instance to `Console.WriteLine()` from a **C# program**.

By contrast, **PowerShell has its own output-formatting system**, described in [`Get-Help about_Format.ps1xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml):

- **Output formats are selected by *data type*** of objects being output.
- Frequently used .NET types have predefined formats.

  - In the case at hand, `System.DateTime`, the output format is defined [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/e177fcaef610f874aa31cd3d85f97162d2859e72/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/Types_Ps1Xml.cs#L79).

    - With a default `System.DateTime` instance, this amounts to (assuming `$dt` as the instance at hand):
      `"{0} {1}" -f $dt.ToLongDateString(), $dt.ToLongTimeString()`
- However, in the *absence* of an output-format definition for a given type, PowerShell does *fall back on* `.ToString()`.

---

**If you want consistent output** in both cases, **call `.ToString()` explicitly** in PowerShell:

```
(Get-Date).ToString()
```

**Caveat**:

- **`.ToString()`** outputs a representation that is **formatted based on the *current culture***, if supported by the type.
- By contrast, **when PowerShell uses *implicit* stringification**, such as in the context of ***expandable strings*** (strings with interpolation, `"..."`; e.g., `"$(Get-Date)"`) it ***always* applies the *invariant* culture**, by design - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375).

Answer (score 2):

C# will by default convert `DateTime` to `string` by calling `ToString` (which generally results in [short-date and long-time format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#Anchor_2)).

Powershell doesn't do that. As per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-6#notes):

> By default, the date-time is displayed in long-date and long-time
>   formats for the system locale.

If you want a consistent, explicit format when outputting `DateTime` as `string` then you **must** always use an explicit date and time format string (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

Comment: C# and Powershell are using two different techniques for converting `DateTime` to `string`. So, in effect, they output different things because they aren't running the 'exact same' code.