# Importing Data From CSV in Powershell Providing UK Date in CSV is Less Than 7 Days Away

Tags: powershell, csv, datetime, import-csv

so I've got a CSV file with 5 headings: name, collectionDate, location, equipmentNotes, manager.

Now my collectionDates are all in UK format so DD/MM/YYYY. I only want to import data from the CSV with collection dates that are 7 days or less in the future.
So today is 17/08, therefore I would only want to pull data from the CSV that is dated between 17/08 to 24/08.

Although Powershell sort of handles datetime objects in UK format if you tell it to, I seem to be unable to then manipulate the date to add on 7 days.

Here is my current code:

```
$today = Get-Date
$thisWeek = $today.AddDays(7)
$thisWeekString = $thisWeek.ToString()
$dateParts = $thisweekString -split " "
$weekFinal = $dateParts[0]

$import = Import-Csv @("\\location\EmailCSV.csv") | Where-Object {$_.collectionDate -lt $weekFinal}
```

Powershell correctly adds 7 days to the datetime to make it 24/08, and then when converting it to a string and removing the time from it, it correctly sets the variable as 24/08/2018. But when I then go to compare them in the Import cmdlet, it just returns all data in the CSV, rather than dates less than 24/08.

I also know Powershell can compare these, because if I create a separate variable $otherDate with 24/08/2018 in it, and then create an if statement that checks if $weekFinal is greater or less than $otherDate, it correctly runs the statement when true.

I've tried using both Where and Where-Object in the Import-Csv cmdlet, but both have returned the same results.

How do I get Powershell to correctly compare $_.collectionDate and $weekFinal to filter the imported data from the csv?

Comment: `$weekFinal` and your `$_` will be strings.  Comparing strings that are dates requires having both values to be known types that are comparable, so converting into `[datetime]` may be the easiest recourse.  I'll add an answer below that seems to fit when I mocked up a CSV like I believe yours to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **easiest to perform *all* calculations and comparisons using `[datetime]` instances - avoid *string* operations** (except for converting a string representation of a date to a `[datetime]` instance).

First, express today's date and 1 week from now as a `[datetime]` instance without a time-of-day component:

```
$today = (Get-Date).Date  # Today's date, without a time component (midnight)
$oneWeekFromToday = $today.AddDays(7)
```

Then use `[datetime]::Parse()` to convert the invariably string-typed CSV column value of interest to a `[datetime]` instance so you can perform proper date-comparison.

```
$import = Import-Csv \\location\EmailCSV.csv | Where-Object { 
  $thisDate = [datetime]::Parse($_.collectionDate)
  # Process this row if its date falls between today and 1 week from now, inclusively.
  $thisDate -ge $today -and $thisDate -le $oneWeekFromToday
}
```

**Important**: **use `[datetime]::Parse('...')`, not a `[datetime] '...'` *cast***, because **only `[datetime]::Parse()` respects the *current culture***'s date and time formats; by design, PowerShell's casts and string interpolation always use the [*invariant* culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture), irrespective of the current culture - for more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375) of mine.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the strings to `[datetime]` in your comparison.  When using a sample set of data, I was able to get the expected results.

```
$import = Import-Csv @("\\location\EmailCSV.csv") | Where-Object {[datetime]$_.collectionDate -lt [datetime]$weekFinal}
```