# Is it possible to initialize a .NET type with properties?

Tags: .net, powershell, constructor, initialization, hashtable

For example I want use this class **Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.HardDiskDrive**

I tried to initialize it by this way:

```
$obbb =  [Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.HardDiskDrive]@{
    Path = 'D:\\TEST\\test\\Virtual Hard Disks\\test.vhdx'
    DiskNumber = $null
    MaximumIOPS = '1000'
    MinimumIOPS = '0'
    QoSPolicyID = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
    SupportPersistentReservations = $false
    WriteHardeningMethod = '0'
    ControllerLocation = '0'
    ControllerNumber = '0'
    ControllerType = '0'
    Name = 'Hard Drive on IDE controller number 0 at location 0'
    PoolName = 'Primordial'
    Id = 'Microsoft:480244F9-44D4-4BFC-B34B-EC3C425D52F7\\83F8638B-8DCA-4152-9EDA-2CA8B33039B4\\0\\0\\D'
    VMId = '480244f9-44d4-4bfc-b34b-ec3c425d52f7'
    VMName = 'test'
    VMSnapshotId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
    VMSnapshotName = ''
    CimSession = $null
    ComputerName = 'NodeTest'
    IsDeleted = $false
    VMCheckpointId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
    VMCheckpointName = ''
}
```

But got this error:

```
Cannot convert the "System.Collections.Hashtable" value of type "System.Collections.Hashtable" to type "Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.HardDiskDrive".
At line:1 char:1
+ $obbb =  [Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.HardDiskDrive]@{
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConvertToFinalInvalidCastException
```

I've also tried different New-Object variants https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object?view=powershell-6

But got errors.

Is it even possible, or not?

Thanks.

Comment: Only in limited circumstances, but generally no - see [this open issue on the PowerShell GitHub asking to make it possible](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7506)

Comment: The `Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.HardDiskDrive` type doesn't have any publicly available constructors, so you can't create its type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Maximilian Burszley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8188846/theincorrigible1) provided the crucial pointer in a comment on the question:

PowerShell's **construction-by-cast-from-hashtable technique** only works if the target type (also) has a **constructor** that is:

- **public**
- *and* **parameter-less**

The error message you're seeing implies that `[Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.HardDiskDrive]` does *not* have such a constructor (see bottom section for how to inspect constructors).

Assuming that a type with such a constructor has ***public* properties that are *settable***, you can **cast from a hashtable whose entries match *any subset* of these properties**, where each entry's key must be the name of such a property and its value a type-compatible one (either already of the same type as the property or convertible to it).
PowerShell instantiates the type using the parameter-less constructor first, and then sets the public properties specified in the hashtable.

Here's a (somewhat contrived) example:

```
$obj = [System.Exception] @{  # just [Exception] works too, because 'System.' is implied
  HResult = 0x8000400
  Source = 'SomeModule'
}
```

The above is the equivalent of:

```
$obj = New-Object System.Exception; $obj.HResult = 0x8000400; $obj.Source = 'SomeModule'
```

---

Because of the need for a parameter-less constructor, the **hashtable technique is currently primarily useful for [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)-like "property bags"**.

**If *all* public constructors of a given type *do* have parameters**, the hashtable technique won't work, and you must ***call a constructor* in order to instantiate the type - either via the static `::new` method (PSv5+) or via the `New-Object` cmdlet**; e.g., to call the `(int year, int month, int day)` overload of the `[System.DateTime]` constructor:

```
New-Object DateTime -ArgumentList 2018, 12, 1 # '-ArgumentList' is optional
[DateTime]::new(2018, 12, 1)  # PSv5+ equivalent
```

<sup>For calling a *single*-parameter constructor, a *cast* may alternative be used - see next section.</sup>

However, [an enhancement is coming](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7506) to PowerShell *Core* <sup>Tip of the hat to [TessellatingHeckler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478656/tessellatingheckler).</sup>
that will allow use of the hashtable technique even with constructors that have parameters, as long as the set of hashtable entries matches a given constructor overload's parameters.

---

Generally, apart from the hashtable case discussed above,  ***casts* (`[<target-type>] <operand>`) and also *implicit conversions* work in the following scenarios**, in order of consideration:

<sup>This information was gleaned from PowerShell Core's source code [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/aec954e3edf59ec5b30e33049d381196783b1555/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/LanguagePrimitives.cs#L1607).</sup>

(a) If the target type is decorated with a [`TypeConverterAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverterattribute) attribute that specifies a custom [`TypeConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter) or [`PSTypeConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pstypeconverter?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) class that supports conversion from the operand type.
Alternatively, these custom converter classes may be associated with types via PowerShell's ETS (extended type system), via [`Update-TypeData -TypeConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/update-typedata))

(b) If the target type supports a static `::Parse()` method for constructing an instance from a *string*:

```
[DateTime] '2018-12-01'

# The above matches `::Parse()` overload `static datetime Parse(string s)`
# However, given that there's also an overload that accepts a 
# System.IFormatProvider argument, PowerShell uses that in order
# to use *culture-invariant* parsing.
# Thus, the above is the equivalent of:
[DateTime]::Parse('2018-12-01', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

More information about PowerShell's use of the *invariant culture* can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375).

(c) If the target type has a public constructor with a single parameter that the operand is type-identical or -compatible with:

```
[Exception] 'Something failed'

# The above matches constructor `Exception(string message)` and is the 
# equivalent of:
New-Object Exception -ArgumentList 'Something failed'
[Exception]::new('Something failed')
```

(d) If the target type defines an implicit or explicit [*conversion operator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/using-conversion-operators) for the operand's type.

(e) If the operand type implements the [`IConvertible`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iconvertible) interface for constructing an equivalent instance of the target type (which is limited to the CLR runtime types (built-in types)).

---

In **PSv5+**, it is easy to **examine the constructors of a given (loaded) type**: call the static `::new` method, without parentheses, which lists the method overloads (signatures) of all publicly available constructors; using the example of type `[System.Random]`:

```
PS> [Random]::new

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
System.Random new()
System.Random new(int Seed)
```

The presence of **a `new()` overload - no parameters - is evidence of a parameter-less public constructor**.

If there's no output at all, the implication is that the type doesn't have any public constructors.