# Powershell Parameter binding ByPropertyName and ByValue

Tags: powershell, parameters

I want to stop a service named "ALG" so I use: `"alg" | stop-service`

It works.

`Get-help stop-service -parameter name` says:

`Pipeline input:true(ByPropertyName, ByValue)` and "alg" is "ByPropertyValue" right?

I want to stop a process named notepad so I use: `"notepad" | stop-process` and I get an error.

`Get-help stop-process -parameter name`

says: `Pipeline input true(ByPropertyName)` and "notepad" is "ByPropertyName"?

Why this error?

Comment: bypropertyname and byvalue are different.

Comment: `"notepad"` is _not_  `ByPropertyName`, it is `ByValue`. The term `ByValue` may be confusing, but all it says is: bind the input object _as a whole_, not by one of its _property values_ (which is `ByPropertyName`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Mathias R. Jessen's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61211497/45375) answer provides a *solution* for piping *strings* (process names) to `Stop-Process`.
- [js2010's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61213381/45375) has the correct *explanation* for *why piping strings to `Stop-Process` doesn't work* (without extra effort), and also offers a helpful technique for tracing parameter binding, but - as of this writing - the answer contains incidental information that confuses the issue a bit.

Let me offer a more detailed explanation:

---

**`Stop-Process`**, unlike `Stop-Service`, **is *not* designed to accept *strings* (process names) as pipeline input.**

While string input *in the abstract* can still work, namely if the strings can automatically be *converted* to one of the data types expected by a command's `ByValue` (whole-object) pipeline-binding parameters, this is *not* the case with `Stop-Process`, because a process *name* (string) cannot (automatically) be converted to a `System.Diagnostics.Process` instance (`-InputObject`)<sup>[1]</sup>.

- When PowerShell considers binding pipeline input to parameter `-Name` during a call, **it looks for an object *with a `Name` property***, because the parameter declaration specifies that pipeline input is accepted *only* if the input object *has a property named for the parameter*:

  - In help topics, such as the one for [`Stop-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-process), this is expressed as **`ByPropertyName`**.
  - In code, it is expressed as the Boolean **`ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName`** property of the [`System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute) type; that is, expressed in PowerShell code, the parameter declaration looks something like: <sup>Note that `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName` is short for `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true`</sup>
    `[Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)] [string[]] $Name`
- A `[string]` ([`System.String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String)) instance such as `"alg"` doesn't have a `Name` property - it is *itself* the name.
- Therefore, in the absence of an automatic *conversion*<sup>[1]</sup> to the `System.Diagnostics.Process` type of the only `ByValue` parameter, `-InputObject`, and in the absence of `Name` and `Id` properties for the `ByPropertyValue` parameters, invocation *fails* with the following error message, which in essence tells you that the pipeline input is invalid (cannot be bound to any parameters):

  - `The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.`

---

**`Stop-Service`, by contrast, *is* designed to accept string input**, because its `-Name` parameter is (also) declared as accepting strings *directly* as input objects, *as a whole*.

- In help topics, such as the one for [`Stop-Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-service), this is expressed as **`ByValue`**.
- In PowerShell code, it is expressed as **`ValueFromPipeline`**:
  `[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)] [string[]] $Name`

Note:

- While a given parameter can be *both* `ByValue` *and* `ByPropertyValue` - which is indeed the case for `Stop-Service`'s `-Name` parameter - that isn't typical.
- Typically, pipeline-binding parameters are declared as *scalars* rather than arrays (e.g., for `Sort-Object`, `-InputObject <PSObject>` rather than `-InputObject <PSObject[]>`), which means that passing multiple arguments is only supported via the pipeline, not by direct argument - see [GitHub issue #4242](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4242) for background information.

---

#### Examining pipeline-binding parameters:

- A command's ***given* parameter**:

```sh
PS> Get-Help Stop-Process -Parameter Name

-Name <String[]>
    Specifies the process names of the processes to stop. You can type multiple process names, separated by commas, or use wildcard characters.
    
    Required?                    true
    Position?                    named
    Default value                None
    Accept pipeline input?       True (ByPropertyName)
    Accept wildcard characters?  true
```

Note the `Accept pipeline input?` line; for a *non*-pipeline-binding parameter, you'd see `False` in the second column.

- ***All* pipeline-binding parameters** supported by a given command:

```sh
PS> Get-Help Stop-Process -Parameter * | Where pipelineInput -like True*

-Id <Int32[]>
    Specifies the process IDs of the processes to stop. To specify multiple IDs, use commas to separate the IDs. To find the PID of a process, type 
    `Get-Process`.
    
    Required?                    true
    Position?                    0
    Default value                None
    Accept pipeline input?       True (ByPropertyName)
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
    

-InputObject <Process[]>
    Specifies the process objects to stop. Enter a variable that contains the objects, or type a command or expression that gets the objects.
    
    Required?                    true
    Position?                    0
    Default value                None
    Accept pipeline input?       True (ByValue)
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
    

-Name <String[]>
    Specifies the process names of the processes to stop. You can type multiple process names, separated by commas, or use wildcard characters.
    
    Required?                    true
    Position?                    named
    Default value                None
    Accept pipeline input?       True (ByPropertyName)
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

Note: The above technique gleans the parameter information from the MAML-based *help file* that *may* accompany a given cmdlet (most *built-in* cmdlets do come with such help files). While the information in the help file *should* correctly reflect the cmdlet's actual parameter definitions and typically does, it isn't guaranteed to. When in doubt, use the following technique instead, which directly examines a cmdlet's actual definition:

```sh
# Lists all pipeline-binding parameters defined by the given cmdlet,
# by examining the actual cmdlet definition.
(Get-Command Stop-Process).ParameterSets.Parameters | 
  Where-Object { $_.ValueFromPipeline -or $_.ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName} |
    Select-Object -Unique Name, Aliases, ParameterType, @{
      Name = 'Accepts pipeline input'
      Expression = { 
        'True ({0})' -f  ($(
           if ($_.ValueFromPipeline) { 'ByValue'}
           if ($_.ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName) { 'ByPropertyName' }
        ) -join ', ')
      }
    } | Sort-Object Name
```

---

<sup>[1] Unless a parameter is declared to support a custom type conversion via a [`System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTransformationAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTransformationAttribute)-derived attribute (which is uncommon), PowerShell's usual conversion rules apply here, which employ several techniques, discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52043964/45375). In the case of [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process), conversion from a string isn't possible, because the target type neither has a single-argument constructor that has a string, nor does it have a static `.Parse()` method. A quick test for convertibility is to attempt a *cast*: `[System.Diagnostics.Process] 'notepad'` fails. By contrast, `[System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController] 'alg'` works, because that type *does* have [a single-parameter constructor that accepts a string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.-ctor#System_ServiceProcess_ServiceController__ctor_System_String_), but note that this conversion does *not* come into play *during parameter binding* in a call to `Stop-Service` such as `'alg' | Stop-Service` - there, the string is bound as-is to the `ByValue` `-Name` parameter.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

If you want to bind an object's value to a parameter *by property name*, either:

1. Pass an object with an appropriately named property:

```bsh
[pscustomobject]@{Name='notepad'} |Stop-Process
# or, for older versions of powershell:
'notepad' |Select @{Name='Name';Expression={$_}} |Stop-Process
```

2. Explicitly bind a pipeline expression to the named parameter:

```bsh
'notepad' |Stop-Process -Name {$_}
```

Comment: does it mean: ByValue= I'm supplying a string (as "alg"), PowerShell finds a property "Name" and stops the service. ByPropertyName= I'm supplying an object, which must have a property "name"?

Comment: `ByValue` = "bind any object of the correct type as-is to this parameter", `ByPropertyName` = "bind the value of a property with the same _name and type_ (if found) to this parameter". PowerShell is a bit more liberal with type conversions than, say C#, but this is generally the principle

Comment: ok, so I still don't get it: stop-process accepts -name ByPropertyName, right?
"notepad" | stop-process gets "name" as a string, why it doesn't work?

Comment: Because the `[string]` "notepad" _doesn't_ have any `Name` property

Comment: The `ByPropertyName` binding means that the parameter looks for a property with that name in the input object. The `String` object doesn't have a `Name` property.

Comment: ok, but using: "alg" | stop-service, "alg" is also supplied ByPropertyName, it's also a string and it doesn't have a property named "name"?

Comment: @Purclot That's because the `Name` parameter on `Stop-Service` is marked with _both_ - it will accept input by property name, and, failing that, it falls back to binding by value

Comment: 1. does it say: "alg" | stop-service "alg" is definitely delivered as ByValue (it's an object, a string,  with a property "Name")?
2. ByValue is the standard parameter anyway?

Comment: @mklement0 I'm writing up an explanation for the "how does this even work" part of the question, but it's quite long-winded

Answer (score 1):

"stop-service -name" can be piped byvalue (string), so it uses that.  Stop-process fails to convert a string to the process type for -inputobject, which is pipe byvalue.  "Stop-process -name" is bypropertyname only.

There's a little more nuance going on here.  A string can be coerced to type servicecontroller, but not to type process.  So a string could theoretically be piped in as -inputobject for stop-service, but not for stop-process.  "stop-service -inputobject alg" works as well, but "stop-process -inputobject notepad" does not.  The inconsistency between these two commands can be confusing.

```
[System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController]'alg'

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Stopped  alg                Application Layer Gateway Service


[system.diagnostics.process]'notepad'
InvalidArgument: Cannot convert the "notepad" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Diagnostics.Process".
```

If you really want to see the bindings:

```
trace-command parameterbinding {'alg' | stop-service} -pshost
trace-command parameterbinding {'notepad' | stop-process} -pshost
```

Comment: hmm, now I'm a bit confused. Stay by Start-Service (or stop-Service): ByValue=the input is a "whole" object of type: [-InputObject] <ServiceController[]>, so using: "alg" | start(stop)-Service, "alg" is definitely NOT an object of type: ServiceController NOR an object of any kind with a property "name", means "alg" will be (must be?) casted to an object of type ServiceController. And as far as I understand the help: ByValue will be allways used in first place?

Comment: I think because -name is string type, 'alg' gets matched to it first.  And "stop-service -name" can by byvalue, but "stop-process -name" cannot be byvalue.

Comment: Thanks for updating, js2010, but the paragraph about a "little more nuance" is still misleading; by contrast, the tip about tracing parameter binding is helpful.