# Wrong object in pipeline when trying to use Get-ChildItem piped to Copy-Item and using $PSItem

Tags: powershell

I am creating a small Powershell script to overwrite all files in folder with the name by 1 source file. So this is a script:

`Version 1`

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\path\to\folder' -Recurse |
Where-Object { $PSItem.Name -eq 'target-file.ps1' } |
Copy-Item -Path $sourceFile -Destination $PSItem -Force -PassThru
```

This script error in:

`The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the | parameters that take pipeline input.`

So what is the `$PSItem` that passed to `Copy-Item` cmdlet ?

`Version 2`

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\path\to\folder' -Recurse |
Where-Object { $PSItem.Name -eq 'target-file.ps1' } |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'FullName' |
Copy-Item -Path $sourceFile -Destination $PSItem -Force -PassThru
```

So here I extract the property `FullName` from `FileInfo` object that run in pipeline just until this line and then it will continue to `Copy-Item` cmdlet ? No ! Error is:

`The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.`

`Version 3`

Let's write what's in pipeline at this moment:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\path\to\folder' -Recurse |
Where-Object { $PSItem.Name -eq 'target-file.ps1' } |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'FullName' |
Write-Host $PSItem
```

It is just `Write-Host` at the end. Result in error:

`The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.`

`Version 4`

Let's create array:

```
$allFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\path\to\folder' -Recurse |
Where-Object { $PSItem.Name -eq 'target-file.ps1' } |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'FullName'

foreach ($item in $allFiles) {
    Write-Host $item
}
```

It is actually output full name to file as expected in the `foreach` loop.

So - why 3 versions above that did not work and result in error ?

Comment: When piping the results of Get-ChildItem to Copy-Item, you can leave out the `-Path` parameter, just tell it where to copy the piped object to in `-Destination` In examples 1 and two, you are trying to use the piped object itself as destination.. wrong order.. Example 3: just remove `| Write-Host $PSItem` to see the result on screen. In all examples you don't need the Where-Object clause, just use the `-Filter` parameter to look for the file with that name

Comment: Probably easier to use XCopy instead of Copy-Item.  From cmd.exe type >Help XCopy for more info.

Comment: it is not a wrong order - I copy my file instead those detected in target folder (overwrite)

Comment: What is `-Destination $PSItem` supposed to mean? Are you trying to copy the file to itself?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon why do you think so ? What actually make you think that I copy file onto itself ? Could you highlight the code that doing so ? And even so - why it is not working ?

Comment: Didn't @Theo already explained problem clearly in his comment? First, you're trying to use `-Path` when this parameter is bound from pipeline then you're trying to use `-Destination $PSItem` when `$PSItem` represents the current object in the pipeline

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon where I use `-Path` parameter bound to pipeline ? Please read the code.... Anyway - why ? why it is not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide the full path of the destination files via a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) named `Destination` to your [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item) call, which makes the pipeline input bind to the `-Destination` parameter:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'C:\path\to\folder' -Recurse -Filter 'target-file.ps1' |
  Select-Object @{ Name='Destination'; Expression={ $_.FullName } } |  
  Copy-Item -LiteralPath $sourceFile -Force -PassThru -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf` and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

---

As for **what you tried**:

- A given cmdlet's pipeline-binding parameters must be bound *either* via the pipeline *or* via an *argument*; if you try *both*, you'll get the error you saw.

  - See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61232707/45375) for how to discover a given cmdlet's pipeline-binding parameters.
  - Re your `... | Copy-Item -Path $sourceFile -Destination $PSItem` attempts:

    - The `Copy-Item` call is complete *without* pipeline input, and the conflicting attempt to *also* bind parameters via the pipeline therefore fails:

      - In *Version 1*, the (filtered) `Get-ChildItem` input binds to `Copy-Item`'s `-LiteralPath` parameter (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60177977/45375)), which conflicts with the bound-by-argument `-Path` parameter.
      - In *Version 2*, the *string* pipeline input binds to `Copy-Item`'s `-Path` parameter, which conflicts with that parameter already having been bound *by argument*.
  - Re your `... | Write-Host $PSItem` attempt:

    - In *Version 3*, the pipeline input binds to [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host)'s `-Object` parameter, which conflicts with that parameter already having been bound *by argument*, positionally.
  - Re your *Version 4*:

    - You're passing *only* an argument to `Write-Host` - and not also pipeline input - which is why the calls succeed.
    - As an aside: [`Write-Host` is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write *to the display only*, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, redirect it to a file. To output a value, use it *by itself*; e.g., `$value` instead of `Write-Host $value` (or use `Write-Output $value`, though that is rarely needed). See also: the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50416448/45375).
- The [automatic `$PSItem` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psitem) (as well as its more commonly used alias, `$_`) cannot meaningfully be used *outside script blocks* (`{ ... }`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55667981/45375).

---

A note on **terminology**:

- A *parameter* is a formal placeholder declared by a *command* (cmdlet, function, or script) that represents input data to operate on at runtime.
- *Binding* a parameter is the act of assigning a value to it, i.e. the act of instantiating a placeholder.

  - Note that binding fundamentally only succeeds if the value to be assigned is either of the same type as the parameter or convertible to the latter.
- There two binding mechanisms:

  - By *argument*, i.e. as a whitespace-separated token following the command name or path; e.g.:

    ```bash
    Write-Host -Object hi!
    ```

    - Because the argument above (the string `'hi!') is preceded by the name of the target parameter, it is called a *named argument*.
    - Many commands also accept arguments *without* indicating the target parameter, in which case it is the argument's *position* among other such arguments, if any, that implies the target parameter; therefore passing values this way is called a *positional argument*, but note any parameters targeted this way must have been *declared* as positional, i.e. must be *positional parameters*; e.g.:

      ```bash
       # Target parameter -Object is positionally implied.
       Write-Host hi!
      ```
  - Via the *pipeline*, i.e. via the output of another command or expression provided as input via `|`, the [pipeline operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#pipeline-operator-); e.g.:

    ```bash
    # Target parameter -Object is implied by the data type
    # of the pipeline input data.
    'hi!' | Write-Host
    ```

    - Parameters that can be bound by pipeline input must be declared as such and are called *pipeline-binding parameters*. Pipeline input can be bound *by value*, i.e. using each input object *as a whole*, or *by property value*, i.e. by the value of the property of each input object whose name is the same as the target parameter's (or any of its aliases).

      - E.g., The `-Id` parameter of `Get-Process` is declared as accepting pipeline input *by property value*, which means that input objects that either have an `.Id` property or a `.PID` property (because `-PID` is an alias of `-Id`) are bound to it; e.g., the following two commands are equivalent to `Get-Process -Id $PID`:

        ```bash
         # By-property-value pipeline binding to parameter -Id
         [pscustomobject] @{ Id = $PID } | Get-Process

         # Ditto, via parameter alias -PID.
         [pscustomobject] @{ PID = $PID } | Get-Process
        ```
    - Note that binding by pipeline means that *each input object* supplies a value to the target parameter, which in turn means that the target command must be designed to process pipeline input *object by object*. In the case of functions and scripts, i.e. commands written in PowerShell, a `process` block is required - see the relevant section of the conceptual [about_Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions#piping-objects-to-functions) help topic.

      - E.g., in terms of output, `'hi', 'there' | Write-Host` is equivalent to `Write-Host 'hi'; Write-Host 'there'`, because the `-Object` parameter is bound *twice* with pipeline binding, once for each input string.
    - As noted, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61232707/45375) has instructions on  how to discover a given command's pipeline-binding parameters, if any, as well as their data types.
- Note:

  - In a given call, a given parameter can only be bound by *one* of the binding mechanisms. Attempting to do *both* results in the `The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command ...` error you saw.
  - By contrast, combining the two binding mechanism to target *different* parameters is a very common and useful technique.
  - Binding *by argument* happens *first*, followed by binding via the *pipeline*, once for each input object.

    - Only parameters that haven't already been bound by arguments are candidates for pipeline binding.

Comment: Could you exalain this:  In Version 3, the string input binds to Write-Host's -Object parameter, which conflicts with that parameter already having been bound by argument, positionally.  ? What is this 'bound by argument' ?

Comment: @AlexF, please see the new bottom section I've just added to the answer.

Comment: So I understand that 'binding' process happens first and then powershell will analyze my arguments ?

Comment: So what you saying here:   `In Version 3, the pipeline input binds to Write-Host's -Object parameter, which conflicts with that parameter already having been bound by argument, positionally. ` Means that Write-Host was first bind and then it was surprised by argument that I provided for the same parameter ?

Comment: @AlexF, yes, `... | Write-Host $foo` means that _argument_ `$foo` (first)  binds to `-Object`, and PowerShell then complains about the (later) attempt to bind `-Object` _again_, via the _pipeline_.

Answer (score 0):

The command `copy-item` accepts pipeline inputs but it tries to automatically matches the piped object AND does use your parameters additionally. In your case, additionally the `destination` parameter only accepts `string` but you tried an object that may contain more than string even can contain an array of objects. In most cases powershell will convert an object to string to make it work, but mutltiple objects AND the auto-matching of parameters result in your problem.

the solution is quite simple with your first example:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\path\to\folder' -Recurse |
Where-Object { $PSItem.Name -eq 'target-file.ps1' } |
foreach {
Copy-Item -Path $sourceFile -Destination $PSItem -Force -PassThru
}
```

On the following page you can read about the commandlet and see that `string` but NOT multiple string[] is the only input for `-destination`:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-5.1#syntax