# Why does Get-CimInstance cause errors in the middle of a pipeline?

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell, `Get-CimInstance` is commonly used to retrieve information about Win32 services. For example, to obtain details about the Windows Time service, we execute:

```
Get-CimInstance -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE name = 'w32time'"
```

This command successfully returns the service information.

We can also attempt to rewrite this using pipes, as demonstrated below:

```
"SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE name = 'w32time'" | Get-CimInstance -Query $_
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
Get-CimInstance: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Query' because it is null.
```

To address this, we can implement a workaround by wrapping `Get-CimInstance -Query $_` with a `ForEach-Object` cmdlet, thus resolving the issue:

```
"SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE name = 'w32time'" | ForEach-Object { Get-CimInstance -Query $_ }
```

Although it raises the question: Why does the command fail without the workaround? Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: see linked answer. different cmdlet, same issue. `$_` is only populated in the context of a scriptblock (`{ ... }`) and represents the _current_ pipeline item

Comment: Note that you _can_ make it work via the pipeline, but only if you provide the query as the value of an object with a `.Query` property; e.g.: `[pscustomobject] @{ Query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service" } | Get-CimInstance`. That is, the `-Query` parameter uses `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName` pipeline binding. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61232707/45375) for how to discover which parameters of a given cmdlet accept pipeline input, and whether a given parameter binds input objects _as a whole_ vs. _by a property whose name matches the parameter_.

Comment: This works too:  `"SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE name = 'w32time'" | Get-CimInstance -Query { $_ } -ComputerName .` The computername parameter is required for some reason.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. As pointed out by @SantiagoSquarzon, `$_` is designed only for specific contexts like `ForEach-Object` and script blocks. I appreciate the solutions offered by both @mklement0 and @js2010, but I'm currently leaning towards @mklement0's approach, as I find the concept of organizing the arguments before passing them to `Get-CimInstance` appealing.