# get IP address of all active network interfaces

Tags: powershell, nic

I'm trying to get the IPv4 address of interfaces that are connected in PowerShell, so I tried this :

```
 Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4  | select InterfaceAlias , IPAddress | Sort-Object InterfaceAlias
```

But I noticed it output more interfaces than expected so I tried this :

```
PS C:\> Get-NetIPInterface -ConnectionState Connected | % { Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceAlias $_.InterfaceAlias } | select InterfaceAlias , IPAddress

InterfaceAlias              IPAddress
--------------              ---------
WiFi                        192.168.1.145
Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1 127.0.0.1
WiFi                        192.168.1.145
Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1 127.0.0.1


PS C:\>
```

But then I see twice the same lines.

I expected this result :

```
InterfaceAlias              IPAddress
--------------              ---------
WiFi                        192.168.1.145
Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1 127.0.0.1


PS C:\>
```

How can this be done ?

Comment: And `Get-NetIPInterface -ConnectionState Connected -AddressFamily IPv4 | Get-NetIPAddress | Select-Object -Property InterfaceAlias, IPAddress` does not provide what you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9196560/olaf) has provided the solution in a comment; let me elaborate:

- [`Get-NetIPInterface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-netipinterface) *itself* allows filtering the interfaces by address family via its `-AddressFamily` parameter.
- The filtered interfaces can *directly* be passed to [`Get-NetIPAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-netipaddress) via the pipeline.

  - The latter offers *several* pipeline-binding parameters, but with `Get-NetIPInterface` output, it is the `.InterfaceAlias` property of the latter's output objects that binds to the former's `-InterfaceAlias` parameter.
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61232707/45375) for how to inspect a given command's pipeline-binding parameters, optionally also programmatically.

Therefore:

```bash
Get-NetIPInterface -ConnectionState Connected -AddressFamily IPv4 | 
  Get-NetIPAddress |
  Select-Object InterfaceAlias, IPAddress |
  Sort-Object InterfaceAlias
```

Comment: Good point, @Olaf: I wasn't aware of the `-AddressFamily` parameter, and I didn't see your comment until after I had posted the original form of my answer - please see my update.

Comment: Already saw it. 