# Parsing a Powershell variable

Tags: powershell, string-formatting

You have all been a great help - let me start by saying that.

I get the below output from a function I run - the data is stored in a variable called `$response`, obtained from an `Invoke-RestMethod` call.

```
@{ResourceType=UserStory; Id=202847; Name=Professional Lines: 2,800,000 Policy Aggregate Limit update}
```

How do i go about parsing these values into new variables so the end result is

```
TP Id:202847 Professional Lines: 2,800,000 Policy Aggregate Limit update
```

Comment: This question is lacking context it seems. How did `$reponse` get created? It looks like a hashtable. therefore it should be in a very usable state now e.g. `$response.ResourceType` You just want 3 variables at the end of the day? What are you going to do with them? So you want to have a flat string for output? Is there an equals sign that got dropped in the copy?

Comment: why do you need to extract the values from their very usable hashtable? you can address them via `$Response['Resource Type']` to get the `UserStory` value. simply address them by the Key to get the Value. ///// if you need to _display_ them on one line, then use the string format operator to build the string you want.

Comment: It _looks_ like a hashtable, but it isn't one; it's actually the stringified version of a _custom object_ (e.g., `"$([pscustomobject] @{ one = 1; two = 2 })"`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What you're showing is the *stringified* form of a *custom object***, which uses a **hashtable-*like* textual representation**.

That custom object's definition looks something like this:

```bash
# Construct a custom object with .ResourceType, .Id, and .Name properties.
$response = [pscustomobject] @{
  ResourceType = 'UserStory'
  Id = 202847
  Name = 'Professional Lines: 2,800,000 Policy Aggregate Limit update'
}
```

**If you include this variable in an *expandable* string (interpolating string)**, you'll get the representation in your question<sup>[1]</sup> - note that **you'll get the same representation if you pass the object to the [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Host) cmdlet**<sup>[2]</sup>, as well as **even with *default* output formatting if `[pscustomobject]` instances are *nested* in *property values***:

```bash
# Note the enclosing "..."
PS> "$response"

@{ResourceType=UserStory; Id=202847; Name=Professional Lines: 2,800,000 Policy Aggregate Limit update}

# Custom object nested in a property value:
PS> [pscustomobject] @{ foo = [pscustomobject] @{ bar = 'baz' } }

foo
---
@{bar=baz}
```

Note that without the enclosing `"..."`, you'd get a nicer, tabular representation, courtesy of PowerShell's output-formatting system.

```bash
PS> $response  # direct output of the object

ResourceType     Id Name
------------     -- ----
UserStory    202847 Professional Lines: 2,800,000 Policy Aggregate Limit update
```

---

**Assuming `$response` is actually still a *custom object*, and not a *string representation of it***, you can simply **access the custom object's properties to build your string**, again **using an *expandable string***:

```bash
PS> "TP Id:$($response.Id) $($response.Name)"
TP Id:202847 Professional Lines: 2,800,000 Policy Aggregate Limit update
```

Note the need to use `$(...)` around the property references - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) for a summary of PowerShell's string-expansion rules.

---

An **alternative approach** is to use the **`-f` operator**, which uses formatting strings like the .NET [`String.Format()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format#Starting) method:

```bash
PS> 'TP ID:{0} {1}' -f $response.Id, $response.Name
TP ID:202847 Professional Lines: 2,800,000 Policy Aggregate Limit update
```

---

<sup>[1] You can also obtain this representation by calling `.psobject.ToString()` on a custom object; curiously, just `.ToString()` doesn't work, as of PowerShell Core 6.1.0; this surprising discrepancy is discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6163).</sup>

<sup>[2] Do note that `Write-Host`'s purpose is to provide *for-display-only* (to-host) output, which bypasses PowerShell's success output stream, and thereby the ability to capture or redirect its output - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375) for more information.</sup>