# Powershell variable not displaying nested object

Tags: powershell

I am sending a GET request that returns an object. Using postman, I get:

```
{
"changedInstance": {
    "change": "Created",
    "instanceAfterChange": {
        "instanceId": "123",
        "schemaName": "RBAC",
        "className": "PermissionCategory",
        "properties": {
            "Name": "IModel Schema Management Service",
            "TypeId": 2,
            "TypeName": "Service Access and Permissions"
        }
    }
}}
```

But when I send a request through Powershell, I get the response:

```
@{change=Created; instanceAfterChange=}
```

The request I have made:

```
$Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $base_url/v2.4/Repositories/BentleyCONNECT--Main/RBAC/PermissionCategory -Method Post -Headers @{'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + $global:token} -Body $postParams -ContentType "application/json"
```

I have checked all the header values and the body, no values are missing.

The property 'instanceAfterChange' is empty, however when I monitor this same request in fiddler, it shows the correct response. My question is, why is Powershell displaying it as empty even though when it is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ConvertFrom-Json` constructs a `[pscustomobject]` instance from your JSON input, and what you're seeing (`@{change=Created; instanceAfterChange=}`) is the default display formatting for the instance's `.changedInstance` property value.

**Due to a bug as of PowerShell 7.0, the default display formatting makes it *appear* as if property `instanceAfterChange` is empty, but it actually isn't**.

- Specifically, the bug is that calling `.ToString()` on `[pscustomobject]` instances unexpectedly yields the *empty string*  - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6163).
- The hashtable-*like* display representation of `[pscustomobject]`s *as property values* - as shown in your question and explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53107600/45375) - involves `.ToString()` calls on *nested* `[pscustomobject]` instances, which is why the bug surfaces.

Therefore, you shouldn't have a problem accessing the nested `[pscustomobject]`s' properties, e.g., `$convertedFromJson.changedInstance.instanceAfterChange.schemaName` should yield `RBAC`.

An easy way to verify that the data *is* there is to convert back to JSON (`ConvertTo-Json`) or to visualize the structure via `Format-Custom`.

A simplified example:

```
$convertedFromJson = '{
  "changedInstance": {
    "instanceAfterChange": {
      "instanceId": "123",
      "schemaName": "RBAC"
    }
  }
}
' | ConvertFrom-Json

# Output as-is: the bug makes .changedInstance appear empty.
$convertedFromJson

'---'

# Access a nested property - this works.
$convertedFromJson.changedInstance.instanceAfterChange.schemaName

'---'

# Visualize the structure of the nested object.
$convertedFromJson | Format-Custom
```

The above yields:

```
changedInstance
---------------
@{instanceAfterChange=}  # DISPLAY BUG: .instanceAfterChange appears empty.
---
RBAC # OK: accessing a property of .instanceAfterChange works.
---

# Visualization of the nested object's structure via Format-Custom
class PSCustomObject
{
  changedInstance = 
    class PSCustomObject
    {
      instanceAfterChange = 
        class PSCustomObject
        {
          instanceId = 123
          schemaName = RBAC
        }
    }
}
```

---