# Powershell ConvertFrom-Json output json format not correct

Tags: json, powershell

I have a json file, i converted that by using ConvertFrom-json but the output i am getting below.

```
Get-Content ".\example1.JSON" | ConvertFrom-Json
```

**Output i am getting as below**

```
---------------------------------
Result                                                                                                                                                                               
------                                                                                                                                                                               
{@{_id=5f0bdeec01c99848bcbbba07; index=0; guid=a1c59de9-94c9-4a53-9a18-61a35457b7a2; isActive=False; balance=$3,782.46; picture=http://placehold.it/32x32; age=28; eyeColor=blue; ...
```

But i want this should be in below format because of "{"Result":" it is not coming in proper format can someone suggest how to overcome ?

```
_id           : 5f0bdeec01c99848bcbbba07
index         : 0
guid          : a1c59de9-94c9-4a53-9a18-61a35457b7a2
isActive      : False
balance       : $3,782.46
picture       : http://placehold.it/32x32
age           : 28
eyeColor      : blue
name          : Tran Rodriquez
gender        : male
company       : VIRVA
email         : tranrodriquez@virva.com
phone         : +1 (908) 426-2103
address       : 222 Crosby Avenue, Frierson, Louisiana, 613
```

Here's sample content of the JSON file:

```
{
  "Result": [
    {
      "id": 10,
      "name": "shirt",
      "color": "red",
      "_id": "5f0bdeec01c99848bcbbba07",
      "host": "tester1"
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "name": "coat",
      "color": "black",
      "price": "$2300"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: without seeing the JSON, no one can really tell. can you post a sanitized, simplified sample that demos your problem?

Comment: {"Result":
[
      {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "shirt",
        "color": "red",
 "_id": "5f0bdeec01c99848bcbbba07",
    "index": 0,
    "guid": "a1c59de9-94c9-4a53-9a18-61a35457b7a2",
    "isActive": false,
    "balance": "$3,782.46",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
    "age": 28,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": "Tran Rodriquez",
    "gender": "male",
    "company": "VIRVA",
        "price": "$123",
 "host" : "tester1"
      }     ]
}

Comment: save the convert output to `$InStuff` and then address the object via `$InStuff.Result` [*grin*]

Comment: Please show us the sanitizes JSON file. Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62882623/edit) link under your question and insert it there as [Formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/22189#22189) text. NOT in a comment, because that becomes unreadable.

Comment: please see this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsQfo.jpg

Comment: If you try my answer with your sample JSON, you'll see that it works (verified in WindPS 5.1 and PS Core 7.0). If it truly doesn't, you'll need to provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the `.Result` property in order to have the (nested) object it contains format properly:

```
(Get-Content -Raw .\example1.JSON | ConvertFrom-Json).Result
```

<sup>Note the use of `-Raw`, which makes `Get-Content` read the file *as a whole, as a single string* - while not strictly necessary, this *speeds up* processing, given that `ConvertFrom-Json` needs to collect all input first anyway.</sup>

---

An object that is nested inside another object as a *property value* is formatted using a single-line, hash-table literal-*like* representation, as you've experienced.

A simple example:

```
PS> [pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1; bar = [pscustomobject] @{ baz = 2 } }

foo bar
--- ---
  1 @{baz=2}
```

Note the representation of the *nested* custom object stored in the `.bar` property.

This hash-table literal-*like* representation is the *stringification* of `[pscustomobject]` instances, as (also) used in *expandable strings*; e.g., `"$([pscustomobject] @{ baz = 2 })"` yields `'@{baz=2}'` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53107600/45375) for details.