# How do I sort an array of objects by one of their property values in Powershell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, sorting

For example, I have a variable, which returns the line with several arrays:

```
@{sourceDSAcn=B; LastSyncResult=0} @{sourceDSAcn=A; LastSyncResult=9} @{sourceDSAcn=C; LastSyncResult=0} @{sourceDSAcn=M; Last SyncResult=10}
```

I want to sort this line alphabetically by one of parameters. In this case - by *sourceDSAcn*, so result must be like that:

```
@{sourceDSAcn=A; LastSyncResult=9} @{sourceDSAcn=B; LastSyncResult=0} @{sourceDSAcn=C; LastSyncResult=0} @{sourceDSAcn=M; Last SyncResult=10}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `$variable |Sort-Object sourceDSAcn`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your output format suggests two things:

- The objects aren't *arrays*, but *custom objects* (`[pscustomobject]` instances).
- You've used the [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Host) cmdet to print these objects to the host (display), which results in the hashtable-literal-*like* representation shown in your question (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53107600/45375)).

  - If, instead, you want the usual rich display formatting you get by default - while still sending the output to the *host* only rather than to the *success output stream* - you can use the [`Out-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Out-Host) cmdlet.
  - Conversely, to produce *data* output to the *pipeline*, use either the [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Output) cmdlet or, preferably, PowerShell's implicit output feature, as shown below; for more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375).

In order to sort (custom) objects by a given *property*, simply pass the name of that property to
[`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Sort-Object?)'s (positionally implied) `-Property` parameter, as [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) helpfully suggests:

```
# Using $variable by itself implicitly sends its value through the pipeline.
# It is equivalent to: Write-Output $variable | ...
$variable | Sort-Object sourceDSAcn # same as: ... | Sort-Object -Property sourceDSAcn
```