# VB.net powershell output contains list and need to return string to DGV

Tags: vb.net, powershell, office365

I'm new around here so take it easy on me... :)

I have a powershell output that looks like so:

[image]

```
UserPrincipalName                 DisplayName  Licenses                         
-----------------                 -----------  --------                         
Brandon@bdtestenv.onmicrosoft.com Brandon Duke {bdtestenv:O365_BUSINESS_PREMIUM}
Test2@bdtestenv.onmicrosoft.com   Test2 2      {bdtestenv:O365_BUSINESS_PREMIUM}
```

And converted the output to a datasource with the following code:

```
 Dim runSpace As Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()
    runSpace.Open()
   
    Dim powerShellCode As String = "Get-MsolUser -All | select UserPrincipalName, DisplayName, Licenses"               'reader.ReadToEnd()
    
    Dim shell = PowerShell.Create()
    shell.Commands.AddScript(powerShellCode)
    Dim results As Collection(Of PSObject) = shell.Invoke()
    Dim tempTable As DataTable = New DataTable()
    tempTable.Columns.Add("UserPrincipalName")
    tempTable.Columns.Add("DisplayName")
    tempTable.Columns.Add("Licenses")

    For Each psObject As PSObject In results
        Dim row As DataRow = tempTable.NewRow()
        row("UserPrincipalName") = psObject.Properties("UserPrincipalName").Value.ToString()
        row("DisplayName") = psObject.Properties("DisplayName").Value.ToString()
        row("Licenses") = psObject.Properties("Licenses").Value.ToString()

        tempTable.Rows.Add(row)
    Next
    Licenses.Guna2DataGridView1.DataSource = tempTable
    '  GridView1.DataSource = tempTable
    ' GridView1.DataBind()
    runSpace.Close()
```

Which works just fine but when I add it to the DataTable the licenses get returned as the following:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List'1[Microsoft.Online.Administration.UserLicense]
```

[image]

I'm needing to convert the list to a string so I can display it in the DataGridView..

Sorry please let me know if you need more information

Thanks ALL!

Answer (score 1):

`.Licenses` contains a *collection* of license objects and not only does the collection *as a whole* not stringify meaningfully with `.ToString()` (`"System.Collections.Generic.List'1[Microsoft.Online.Administration.UserLicense]"`), neither do its elements (`"Microsoft.Online.Administration.UserLicense"`).

Perhaps the simplest way **to get a meaningful single-string representation of the `.Licenses` collection** is to modify your PowerShell command to create such a representation with the help of a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties):

```vb
' Note the calculated property at the end:
' @{ Name='Licenses'; Expression={ $_.Licenses.AccountSkuId -join ' ' }
Dim powerShellCode As String = "Get-MsolUser -All | select UserPrincipalName, DisplayName, @{ Name='Licenses'; Expression={ $_.Licenses.AccountSkuId -join ' ' } }"
```

`$_.Licenses.AccountSkuId` extracts the `.AccountSkuId` property values from all license objects contained in the collection returned by `.Licenses` and `-join ' '` joins them with a space as the separator to form a list of values as a single string (adjust the separator string as needed).

`.AccountSkuId` is the property assumed to yield a meaningful representation of a given instance of .NET type `[Microsoft.Online.Administration.UserLicense]` (which doesn't appear to be documented).

To provide a simple example:

```sh
# A custom class that simulates the license class
class UserLicense {
  [string] $AccountSkuId
  UserLicense([string] $name) { $this.AccountSkuId = $name }
}

# Simulate an array of users returned from Get-MsolUser
$users = @([pscustomobject] @{
  UserPrincipalName = 'jdoe@example.org'
  DisplayName = 'Jane Doe'
  Licenses = [Collections.Generic.List[UserLicense]] ([UserLicense]::new('LicenseA'), [UserLicense]::new('LicenseB')) 
})

# Apply the Select-Object call with the calculated user, and
# convert it to CSV to demonstrate how the properties stringify.
$users | 
  Select-Object UserPrincipalName, DisplayName, @{ Name='Licenses'; Expression={ $_.Licenses.AccountSkuId -join ' ' } } |
    ConvertTo-Csv
```

Output, showing that the *calculated* `Licenses` property stringifies meaningfully:

```
"UserPrincipalName","DisplayName","Licenses"
"jdoe@example.org","Jane Doe","LicenseA LicenseB"
```

If you had just used `Select-Object UserPrincipalName, DisplayName, Licenses`, the original problem would surface:

```
"UserPrincipalName","DisplayName","Licenses"
"jdoe@example.org","Jane Doe","System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UserLicense]"
```

Also note that using [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)'s `-ExpandProperty` parameter (as recommended in [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71805453/45375)) is *not* a general solution, as it results in *multiple* output objects per user object if the `.Licenses` collection happens to contain more than one license - unless this kind of denormalization is what you want:

```sh
# !! -ExpandProperty creates a separate output object for each license.
$users | 
  Select-Object UserPrincipalName, DisplayName -ExpandProperty Licenses | 
    ConvertTo-Csv
```

Output, which now comprises *two* objects, one for each license:

```
"UserPrincipalName","DisplayName","AccountSkuId"
"jdoe@example.org","Jane Doe","LicenseA"
"jdoe@example.org","Jane Doe","LicenseB"
```

Also note how the *column headers changed*: the reason is that, due to `-ExpandProperty`, each output object is now a `[UserLicense]` instance, *decorated with* the other two requested properties, `UserPrincipalName` and `DisplayName`. The `[UserLicense]` instance itself is represented by its one public property, `AccountSkuId`.

---

##### Optional reading: Why PowerShell's default output formatting resulted in a meaningful representation:

As shown in the screenshot in the question, outputting the PowerShell command to the PowerShell console *did* result in meaningful stringification of the `.Licenses` property values, courtesy of PowerShell's rich for-display [output-formatting system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/format/formatting-file-overview):

For types other than `[pscustomobject]`<sup>[1]</sup>, PowerShell looks for a (public) property whose name *is or ends in `Id`* (irrespective of case) and then uses *that property's value* to represent the object as a whole.<sup>[2]</sup> If no such property exists, the `.ToString()` return value is used.

The logic is that such a property is assumed to represent an ID, i.e. an identifying piece of information that is therefore a suitable representation of the object as a whole.

In the case at hand, PowerShell therefore implicitly represented the `[Microsoft.Online.Administration.UserLicense]` instances by their `. AccountSkuId`  property values, which is what the code at the top does explicitly.

Here's a simplified example:

```sh
# Define a sample class.
class Foo {
  [int] $Foo = 1
  # This property's value will be used in the output formatting,
  # because it ends in "id"
  [string] $SomeId
  Foo([string] $id) { $this.SomeId = $id }
}

# Construct a custom object and output it to the console.
# Its .Collection property contains two [Foo] instances with
# distinct .SomeId values.
[pscustomobject] @{
      # Note: Showing the objects by the first "id"-suffixed property's values 
      #       would NOT be applied if the .Collection property were assigned as *scalar*.
Collection = [Foo]::new('Hi'), [Foo]::new('there')
}
```

This results in the following display output:

```
Collection
----------
{Hi, there}
```

Note the use of the `.SomeId` property values to represent the instances.
If no ID-like property existed, the `[Foo]` instances would be represented by their `.ToString()` value, which is just their *type name*, namely `Foo`.<sup>[3]</sup>

---

<sup>[1] Instances of `[pscustomobject]` are represented with *all* their properties, using a hashtable-*like* representation, such as `@{foo=bar; baz=quux}` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53107600/45375) for more information.</sup>

<sup>[2] If *multiple* such properties exist, the *first* one, in definition order, is used.</sup>

<sup>[3] The type names of PowerShell custom `class`es have no namespace component, unlike regular .NET types (e.g. `Microsoft.Online.Administration.UserLicense`). Returning just the full type name from `.ToString()` calls on instances of the type is the *default* behavior and applies to most types. However, certain types *override* the `.ToString()` method in order to provide a more meaningful representation; e.g., [`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex) returns the text of the regular expression from `.ToString()`.</sup>

Comment: @Bronzexe - yeah, sorry: I didn't consider that `Microsoft.Online.Administration.UserLicense` instances do not stringify meaningfully, so you'll have to choose a _property_ of each, and from what I can tell that property is `.AccountSkuId`. Please see my update, which also demonstrates that using `-ExpandProperty` is _not_ a general solution - unless you want a separate output object for each license associated with a given user.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix my issue using -ExpandProperty

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Please see my answer for why this isn't a general solution - unless you want a separate output object for each license associated with a given user. (If all users only ever have _one_ license in their `.Licenses` collection, it'll work, however).

Comment: You don't spell it out, but I assume that you used `Get-MsolUser -All | select -ExpandProperty Licenses UserPrincipalName, DisplayName`.
Leaving the potential denormalization problem aside, it's important to note that this changes the structure of the output, so that
`row("Licenses") = psObject.Properties("Licenses").Value.ToString()` would have to be changed to `row("Licenses") = psObject.Properties("AccountSkuId").Value.ToString()`

Comment: I appreciate that you tried to share a solution, but in its current form I believe your answer to be unhelpful to future readers.
That said, if _you_ believe that it is the right solution, you can self-accept your answer, based on the general advice in the next comment: