# Store foldername in powershell variable

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to save the name of folder into a variable.

`$foldername = Get-ItemProperty -Path C:\test* | Select-Object Name`

`Get-Variable -Name foldername`

`@{Name=test123}`

How can i remove the @{} in the output of the variable?

Comment: What you want is [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem), and have a look at the `-ExpandProperty` parameter for Select-Object

Comment: Agreeing with Theos comment above. You could also just use `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test -Name -Directory`; *assuming you're on PSv3*. Where `-Name` only returns the name property, and `-Directory` only returns folders. Edit: *Believe I misread the question, but still leaving my comment here for educational purposes*.

Comment: In short: [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) (`select`) by default returns _a `[pscustomobject]` instance_ that has the _requested properties_ - even when you're only asking for a _single_ property. To get only that property's _value_, use `-ExpandProperty $propertyName` instead - see the [linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48807857/45375) for details and alternatives, notably the ability to simply use `(...).$propertyName`

Comment: As for the hashtable-_like_ representation you saw in the display output from `Get-Variable` (`@{Name=test123}`): It is unrelated to hashtables and not meant for programmatic processing. PowerShell uses this format when `[pscustomobject]` instances, such as created by `Select-Object`, are coerced to _strings_ - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53107600/45375) for more information.

Comment: To summarize: Mathias' answer _bypasses_ your original problem via the use of `Get-ItemPropertyValue`, but both `Get-ItemProperty` and `Get-ItemPropertyValue` are rarely used in the context of file-system operations. More idiomatic solutions are (note that due to use of wildcards _multiple_ names may be returned): `$foldername = (Get-ChildItem C:\test*).Name` or `$foldername = Get-ChildItem C:\test* -Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Get-ItemPropertyValue` instead of `Get-ItemProperty`:

```
$foldername = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path C:\test* -Name Name
```

Comment: One more question. How can manipulate the content of the variable. For example if there is "new" in the name of folder and i want to remove the "new" in the variable.

Comment: `$foldername = $foldername.Substring(3)` in a subsequent statement (or `$foldername = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path C:\test* -Name Name |ForEach-Object Substring 3`)