# What does this mean in PowerShell @{propName=value}

Tags: powershell

For a list of files (photos), I'm trying to check if they have EXIF info from a camera or not and only further process photos that *aren't* from a camera. I thought I would just check if the CameraModel EXIF prop is blank, but I'm stuck.

I have this code:

```
$scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$dir = Split-Path $scriptpath

Write-Host $dir
Invoke-Expression -Command $($dir + "\Get-FileMetaData.ps1")

Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Directory |
Foreach-Object {
    $date_str = $_.Name + '-01-01 00:00:00'
    $date = $(Get-Date -Date $date_str)
    Write-Host $_.FullName
    Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Filter "*.jpg" |
        Foreach-Object {
            Write-Host $_.Name
            $md = Get-FileMetaData -File $_.FullName
            $camModel = $($md | Select "CameraModel")
            Write-Host $($camModel | Select-Object -Property "CameraModel")
        }
}
```

Where Get-FileMetaData from from here https://evotec.xyz/getting-file-metadata-with-powershell-similar-to-what-windows-explorer-provides/ halfway down.

This returns

```
DSC_0132.JPG
@{CameraModel=NIKON D80}
ScannedImage001.JPG
@{CameraModel=}
```

My question is, how do I check if this is blank, as in the bottom result `@{CameraModel=}`?
What does `@{CameraModel=}` actually mean? What is the `@{}` signify?

Edit:
Thanks @mlkement0!

My final script is below, which sets the creation and last modified dates of non-camera JPGs to 1st Jan where the year is the year in the folder name:

```
$scriptpath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$dir = Split-Path $scriptpath

Write-Host $dir
Invoke-Expression -Command $($dir + "\Get-FileMetaData.ps1")

Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Directory |
Foreach-Object {
    $date_str = $_.Name + '-01-01 00:00:00'
    $date = $(Get-Date -Date $date_str)
    Write-Host $_.FullName
    Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Filter "*.jpg" |
        Foreach-Object {
            Write-Host $_.Name
            $md = Get-FileMetaData -File $_.FullName
            $camModel = $md.CameraModel
            if ($camModel -like ''){
                $(get-item $_.FullName).CreationTime = $date
                $(get-item $_.FullName).LastWriteTime = $date
                Write-Host $("Set date to " + $date)
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Cool, so I've replaced with `$camModel = $($md | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "CameraModel")`, but it fails on the photo without a CameraModel (prop not found) - how can I instead return this as something I can use? or how can I handle that error?
`Select-Object : Property "CameraModel" cannot be found.`
And why does this produce an error, but using `Select-Object -Property "CameraModel"` doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few **general points**:

- [`Write-Host` is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write *to the display only*, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, or redirect it to a file. To output a value, use it *by itself*; e.g, `$value`, instead of [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) `$value` (or use [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) `$value`, but that is rarely needed); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375). To explicitly print only to the display *but with rich formatting*, use [`Out-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-host).
- Therefore, to get proper output formatting, just use `$_.Name` and `$camModel | Select-Object -Property "CameraModel"` *as-is* - no need for `Write-Host` or even `Write-Output`, which is *implied*. If you want just the camera model *value*, use `-ExpandProperty` instead of `Property`.

---

As for your **specific questions**:

> how do I check if this is blank, as in the bottom result `@{CameraModel=}`

```bash
$md = Get-FileMetaData -File $_.FullName

# Just use property access to get the camera model *value*.
# If no such property exists, $null is returned
# (except if Set-StrictMode -Version 2 or above is in effect).
$camModel = $md.CameraModel 

if ($camModel -like '' {
  "Camera model is $null or the empty string."
}
```

> What does `@{CameraModel=}` actually mean? What is the `@{}` signify?

This hashtable-*like* representation  is unrelated to actual [hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) and not meant for programmatic processing.

PowerShell uses this *for-display* representation when `[pscustomobject]` instances, such as created by `Select-Object`, are coerced to *strings*, such as when you use `Write-Host` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53107600/45375) for more information.

---

**Optional reading: Pitfall when using [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) with `-ExpandProperty` for extracting property values:**

The above solution uses simple *property access* (dot notation) to get the value of the `$md` object's `.CameraModel` property, i.e. `$md.CameraModel`

This syntactically simple approach even works when directly applied to expressions and commands enclosed in `(...)`, and even when the object being operated on is a *collection* of objects, due to a feature called [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration)); e.g., in the following example the `.Year` property values of the input objects are returned as an *array* (`[object[]]`):

```bash
((Get-Date), (Get-Date).AddYears(1)).Year # e.g. -> @(2022, 2023)
```

If the return values are to be collected in memory anyway, there is therefore no good reason to achieve the same tasks via a - invariably *slower* - `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` call; e.g.:

```bash
# Same result as above.
(Get-Date), (Get-Date).AddYears(1) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Year
```

Another reason to avoid `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` is an inconsistency you've discovered:

**Unlike with `-Property`, `-ExpandProperty` *reports an error* for any input object that happens not to have that property**; e.g.:

```bash
# -> Outputs 1, for the first object, but then emits an 
#    ERROR: 'Select-Object: Property "Prop" cannot be found.'
[pscustomobject] @{ Prop=1 }, [pscustomobject] @{ } | 
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty Prop
```

With `-Property`, by contrast, you'd get a `[pscsutomobject]` instance whose `.Prop` value is `$null` for any input object that doesn't have a `.Prop` property - no error occurs.
This surprising inconsistency is the subject of [GitHub issue #18416](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18416). [*Update*: a [decision was made not to change this behavior and merely *document* it](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18416#issuecomment-1470322631).]

**Strict mode ([`Set-StrictMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode)) considerations**:

- As a cmdlet, `Select-Object` is *not* affected by the strict mode that is in effect:

  - The (unexpected) errors that occur with `-ExpandProperty` for non-existent properties are reported *per input object* (and are therefore *non-terminating* errors), which means that values *are* still reported for any input objects that *do* have the requested property.
- By contrast, attempts to access a non-existent property (with `.`, the [member-access operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#member-access-operator-)) only cause an error if `Set-StrictMode -Version 2` or higher is in effect:

  - Using `.` to access a non-existent property results in a *statement-terminating* error, which means that the entire statement is instantly terminated, with the attempted property access producing *no* (data) output.
  - Since this also applies to member-access enumeration, there is *no* (data) output even if *some* of the input objects have the targeted property - unlike with `Select-Object -ExpandProperty`; e.g.:

    ```bash
    # Set strict mode to a version that enforces property existence.
    Set-StrictMode -Version 2

    # !! This ONLY produces an ERROR - it doesn't also output
    # !! 1, even though the first input object has a .Prop property.
    ([pscustomobject] @{ Prop=1 }, [pscustomobject] @{ }).Prop
    ```

Comment: Thanks! I was just using Write-Host to help in writing/debugging. I'm SUPER new to PowerShell, used to Python and other languages. PS is so different... Your answer makes perfect sense, cheers!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @njminchin; my pleasure. For ad-hoc debugging _with proper formatting_, use `... | Out-Host` instead. As for why `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` - unlike `-Property` - reports an _error_ if no such property exists: excellent question: let's see what the official explanation is: [GitHub issue #18416](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18416)

Comment: @njminchin, another tip: `(...)` (rather than `$(...)`) is normally sufficient for passing the output from an expression or command as an argument to another command; e.g. `Out-Host -InputObject (Get-Date | Select-Object Month, Year)` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58248195/45375).