# How to display values from a powershell array created by select-string

Tags: arrays, powershell, select-string

I have an array and use select-string to find duplicates.

```
$2 = $arraySNOW | Select-String -Pattern $request
```

The process usually finds 2 items and but each item is now rapped inside `@{}` object and I can not access the value for a specific property

```
$2[0]

@{number=63887630; request=abc560vi}

$2 | Get-Member
TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo

$2.gettype()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

How to pull the value of the request for both items in `$2`?

Comment: `Select-String` as the name implies is for strings not objects.... `$arraySNOW | Where-Object Request -Match $request`

Comment: Hi Santiago, why the variable type shows that it is Object[] and System.Array?

Comment: you are right - the property Line is a string! 
  $2[0].line.gettype()

  IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
  -------- -------- ----                                     --------
  True     True     String                                   System.Object

Thank you!

Comment: If you get only one value PS will not make it an array.  To force an array use : $2 = @($arraySNOW | Select-String -Pattern $request)

Comment: @Dijkgraaf has done it for this post, but please [format your posts properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) has provided the crucial pointer:

**[`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) is for *string* searches, whereas you want *OO* techniques to filter your *objects*, so you should use [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object)** to filter your objects by a *property value* of interest:

```bash
# Filters the input objects by whether their .Request property
# matches the specified regex pattern.
$arraySNOW | Where-Object Request -match $request
```

The above passes the matching input objects through, so you can access their properties as needed; e.g., to get the `.number` property values of the matching objects:

```bash
$arraySNOW | Where-Object request -match $request |
  ForEach-Object number  # alternatively: Select-Object -ExpandProperty number
```

Or, more succinctly, using [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration):

```bash
($arraySNOW | Where-Object request -match $request).number
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

`$arraySNOW | Select-String -Pattern $request` returns any number of [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) instances describing the *string* matches performed on the input objects.

- Their `.Line` property contains the *text* of the input line or stringified input object (see below) that was matched; in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), you can obtain this text *directly* with the `-Raw` switch.

If `Select-Object` emits *two ore more* objects and you capture them in a *variables* (`$2 = ...`) PowerShell automatically collects them in an `[object[]]` (`System.Object[]`) array for you.

- Piping an array (a list-like enumerable) to [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member) invariably results in the array's *enumeration*, so that `Get-Member` reports the *distinct* types among its *elements* - hence the report of type `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`
- By contrast, calling [`.GetType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Object.GetType) on any object - whether it is a scalar or an array / list / collection - reports its *own* type.

The for-display representation of a `MatchInfo` instance you saw with `$2[0]` is in essence the value of its `.Line` property:

- *Non-string* input to `Select-Object` is *implicitly stringified*, and the stringified value is both used for matching and reported via the `.Line` property.
- Therefore, you lose the *object* identity of the input, and simply get a *string representation* of it.

  - The specific form of the string representation you saw - `@{number=63887630; request=abc560vi}` *resembles* PowerShell [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) literals - but is, in fact, how [`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_PSCustomObject) instances are stringified - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53107600/45375) for details.
  - With many other types, the implicit stringification results in *useless* representations, namely simply the full *type name* of the input object, given that `.ToString()` stringification (with some custom functionality overlaid) is applied (e.g., stringifying a hashtable results in string `'System.Collections.Hashtable'`; try `@{ foo = 1 }.ToString()`)
  - Given that PowerShell has a rich for-display output-formatting system that provides much more helpful representations of most types, it is unfortunate that `Select-String` doesn't apply PowerShell's formatting *implicitly*; see [GitHub issue #10726](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10726) for a discussion.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!. I was avoiding Where-Object because I am searching reports with around 20K lines. I thought that select-string would preform better.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @TihomirBuncic. For better performance, you can use the [intrinsic `.Where()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where), and using a [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) loop with an `if` statement may perform best.

Answer (score 0):

What you are likely looking for is the "Line" Property.

Here is a small example:

```
$arraySNOW = @("One Number", "A Name", "Another Number")
$request = "number"

$2 = $arraySNOW | Select-String -Pattern $request 
$2 | % { $_.Line }
```

Outputs the two lines which matched:

```
One Number
Another Number
```

You can also just write `$2.Line` instead of `$2 | % { $_.Line }` which will effectively do the same thing for you. PowerShell is smart! But I find it a bit more terse for someone reading your script and they may not realize you are doing an operation for each element of an array.

Comment: Thank you Tolga. The issue was that I need to get value from the string in .Line that was formatted as an object.