# Powershell Hashtable with Initial Capacity

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I was wondering how you declare a hashtable in powershell with an initial capacity. I know how large I want it to be but I have to assign the values to it in a loop.

So something like:

```
$hashtable = @{} (100)
```

Comment: `[Hashtable]::New(100)` or (older versions) `New-Object System.Collections.Hashtable 100`. Be aware that pre-specifying the capacity usually doesn't win you much in terms of memory or runtime, though; it already implements generous dynamic sizing, and if your guess is off the benefits basically evaporate.

Comment: I would be more curious as to why you are doing this. Just in case there is a better path to be going down to accomplish your goal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JeroenMostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) makes a good point as to why you may not *need* to specify an initial capacity:

> Be aware that pre-specifying the capacity usually doesn't win you much in terms of memory or runtime, though; it already implements generous dynamic sizing, and if your guess is off, the benefits basically evaporate.

If you do need to **specify the initial capacity**:

<sup>Tip of the hat to [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) for his help.</sup>

Because PowerShell's hashtables are always *case-insensitive* with respect to key lookups, `[hashtable]::new(100)` does *not* work, unfortunately, because the default is to create a case-*sensitive* hashtable.

Therefore, use of a `[System.Collections.Hashtable]` constructor overload that allows specifying the key-equality comparison method is required, so that you can **specify a culture-sensitive, case-insensitive equality comparer** to match PowerShell's usual hashtable behavior in **v6.1-**<sup>[1]</sup>:

```
# PSv5+ syntax
$hashtable = [hashtable]::new(100, [StringComparer]::CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)

# PSv4- syntax
$hashtable = New-Object hashtable 100, ([StringComparer]::CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

PetSerAl offers the following alternative:

```
$hashtable = [System.Collections.Specialized.CollectionsUtil]::CreateCaseInsensitiveHashtable(100)
```

Note: In **v6.2+** PowerShell **now uses an *ordinal* string comparer** (`[StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase`).

Additionally, as PetSerAl points out, **PowerShell v6.1- *caches* the key-equality comparer for the current session - so an in-session change of the current culture is *ignored***. If you want to emulate this - questionable - behavior, PetSerAl provides the following command:

```
$hashtable = [hashtable]::new(100,
 [hashtable].GetProperty(
   'EqualityComparer',
   [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]'NonPublic, Instance'
 ).GetValue(@{}))
```

<sup>Despite the use of reflection to access a *non-public* property, this approach should be safe, because the targeted property's access modifier is `protected`, which means it has a "contract" with derived public classes and won't go away.</sup>

---

Note that another way to optimize a hashtable is to specify its **load factor**, and there are constructor overloads for specifying that factor as well.

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.-ctor#System_Collections_Hashtable__ctor) (emphasis added):

> A hash table's **capacity** is used to calculate the optimal number of hash table buckets based on the load factor. Capacity is automatically increased as required.
>
> The **load factor** is the maximum ratio of elements to buckets. A smaller load factor means faster lookup at the cost of increased memory consumption.
>
> When the actual load factor reaches the specified load factor, the number of buckets is automatically increased to the smallest prime number that is larger than twice the current number of buckets.

---

<sup>[1] Note that in many contexts PowerShell uses the *invariant culture* for string operations, but hashtables seem to be an exception - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8280) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375).

[The **v6.1-** source code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/877b9a9fbf0bed3876de3c00ff34525aba96c749/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/parser/Compiler.cs#L5694-L5696) reveals the use of `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` in PowerShell's hashtable constructor, and the [**v6.2+** source code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/1e5655b48cdad707ee3678435c4b587c0856a35c/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/parser/Compiler.cs#L6442-L6444) now shows use of *ordinal* (case-insensitive) comparison.</sup>

Comment: Great stuff, @PetSerAl - answer updated again, please have a look. Any idea why hashtables were made culture-sensitive in PowerShell, given the generally culture-invariant philosophy?

Comment: Possibly it was made that way in the start by accident, and then kept this way for compatibility. Same as from string conversions for cmdlet parameters.