# Add sexagesimal times in powershell

Tags: powershell, timespan, ffprobe

I'm using `ffprobe` to get the sexagesimal time and after trimming the last three (unnecessary) digits I get the following format:

```
#examples
 0:05:51.15 
11:03:15.24
```

Is there a way to add these 2 so that the result is `11:09:06.39` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can **cast the strings to type `[timespan]`**, which allows you to perform arithmetic on the resulting objects, and to apply custom formatting on output:

```
PS> ([timespan] ' 0:05:51.15' + [timespan] '11:03:15.24').ToString('h\:mm\:ss\.ff')
11:09:06.39
```

Note: If there's a chance that the resulting time span exceeds 24 hours, more work is needed.<sup>[1]</sup>

Note how **`\`-escaping must be used to specify the output separators *as literals***.
In this case, the simpler `.ToString('g')` would have yielded the same output, but only in *cultures that use `.` as the decimal separator*, because the standard `g` format specifier is culture-*sensitive*.
See the [`[timespan]::ToString()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tostring) as well as the documentation on [standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings) and [custom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings) time-span format specifiers.

By contrast, **PowerShell uses the [*invariant culture*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture) when interpreting the input format** cast to `[timespan]`, where `.` is the decimal separator; similarly, using a `[timespan]` instance **in *expandable strings*** yields a culture-invariant representation; e.g.:

- `[timespan] '11:03:15.24'` *always* works, irrespective of the current culture, because the invariant culture expects `.` as the decimal separator.
- `"$([timespan] '1' - 1)"` *always* yields `23:59:59.9999999`, irrespective of the current culture<sup>[2]</sup>.

As [No Refunds No Returns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/210754/no-refunds-no-returns) notes, if you're **dealing with differently formatted input**, **possibly from a different culture**, you can use [`[timespan]::Parse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parse) / [`[timespan]::ParseExact()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parseexact)  / [`[timespan]::TryParseExact()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tryparseexact)

---

**Parsing the *standard* formats of a given culture**:

```
[timespan]::Parse(' 0:05:51,15', 'fr-FR') # OK
```

Note the `,` as the decimal separator.

If you *omit* the culture argument (or pass `$null`), the *current* culture is applied. Note how that differs from using a `[timespan]` *cast*, which is always culture-*invariant* (and assumes `.` as the decimal separator).

---

**Parsing with a *custom* format:**

```
[timespan]::ParseExact(' 0:05:51,15'.Trim(), 'h\:mm\:ss\,ff', $null) # OK
```

Note that using **such a literal *custom* format is *never* culture-sensitive**, because **all the separators must be specified as - escaped - literals** (e.g., `\:`), so `$null` is passed as the culture argument (`IFormatProvider`).
Conversely, passing a specific culture only makes sense with the culture-sensitive *standard* format specifiers, `g` and `G`.

**Parsing with a *culture-aware custom* format:**

If you don't know what culture will be in effect at runtime, but you want to respect that culture's decimal separator *in combination with a custom format*, you need to **dynamically embed the current culture's decimal separator in your custom format string**:

```
$tsText = ' 0:05:51.15'
[timespan]::ParseExact($tsText.Trim(), 
  ('h\:mm\:ss\{0}ff' -f [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator),
  $null
) # OK in cultures that use "." as the decimal separator
```

---

<sup>[1] `h` and `hh` only ever reflect the hours *not included in full days* in the input time span. To reflect the number of days too, prepend something like `d\.` - there is *no* format specifier that allows you express the *total number of hours across multiple days*, but you can use general-purpose string formatting to achieve that - do note, however, that you'll also need *custom parsing code* in order to convert the resulting string back to a `[timespan]` instance:

`$ts = [timespan] ' 1:05:51.15' + [timespan] '23:03:15.24'`

`'{0}:{1:mm\:ss\.ff}' -f [Math]::Floor($ts.TotalHours), $ts`</sup>

<sup>[2] At the *.NET* level, calling `.ToString()` on objects typically yields a culture-*sensitive* representation (if the type supports it), but with `[timespan]` the output happens to be culture-invariant. By contrast, *PowerShell* explicitly uses the *invariant culture* behind the scenes in casts and string interpolation, so that `"$var"` and `$var.ToString()` may *not* yield the same representation - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375) for details.</sup>

Comment: **edit** I added your footnote solution to my main script and noticed that an error occurs when trying to do somethings like `$ts = [timespan] ' 1:05:51.15' + [timespan] '24:03:15.24'` >> `Cannot convert value "24:03:15.24" to type "System.TimeSpan". Error: "The TimeSpan could not be parsed because at least
one of the numeric components is out of range or contains too many digits."` Does this mean that _timespan_ won't be able to handle it if _hours>24_?

Comment: @YTZ: Yes, as a _string_ representation you won't be able to cast that or parse it via a standard or custom format - you'd need custom parsing code. Adding the days component would fix that, however. Generally, try to convert from strings early, then perform all calculations based on `[timespan]` instances, then convert back to a string representation, if needed.