# Select-String Doesn't Show All Matches With Get-AppxPackage

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, grep, select-string

I get all the packages installed on my PC using `Get-AppxPackage` and I'm trying to find all the matches in that with N lines before and after using `Select-String`.

However, the select string is only showing a matches as single line and it's not showing all the matches either. This only happens when I pipe the output from `Get-AppxPackage` and not if I write it to a file and then do `cat <filename> | select-string ...`.

As you can see in the example below the two results of using pipe and `cat`. I'm interested in results like from `cat` i.e. detailed info about the app.

So what am I doing wrong here? Why is the output different?

---

Example (everyone should have MS Edge so I'll use that as an example) :

```bsh
PS > Get-AppxPackage | Select-String -pattern 'edge' -context 3, 3 -allmatches

  Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_10.0.18362.329_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
  Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_1.13.0.18362_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
  Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin_1000.18362.329.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
> Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_44.18362.329.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe
  Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost_10.0.18362.329_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
  Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_10.0.18362.329_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
  Windows.CBSPreview_10.0.18362.329_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
  Microsoft.Windows.Apprep.ChxApp_1000.18362.329.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
  Microsoft.Win32WebViewHost_10.0.18362.329_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
  Microsoft.PPIProjection_10.0.18362.329_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
> Microsoft.MicrosoftEdgeDevToolsClient_1000.18362.329.0_neutral_neutral_8wekyb3d8bbwe
  Microsoft.LockApp_10.0.18362.329_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy
> Microsoft.EdgeDevtoolsPlugin_10.0.18362.329_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
  Microsoft.ECApp_10.0.18362.329_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe
  Microsoft.CredDialogHost_10.0.18362.329_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy
  Microsoft.BioEnrollment_10.0.18362.329_neutral__cw5n1h2txyewy

PS > cat .\appx-packages.txt | select-string -pattern 'edge' -context 3, 3 -allmatches

  SignatureKind     : System
  Status            : Ok

> Name              : Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge
  Publisher         : CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
  Architecture      : Neutral
  ResourceId        :
  Version           : 44.18362.329.0
> PackageFullName   : Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_44.18362.329.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe
> InstallLocation   : C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe
  IsFramework       : False
> PackageFamilyName : Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe
  PublisherId       : 8wekyb3d8bbwe
  IsResourcePackage : False
  IsBundle          : False
  SignatureKind     : System
  Status            : Ok

> Name              : Microsoft.MicrosoftEdgeDevToolsClient
  Publisher         : CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
  Architecture      : Neutral
  ResourceId        : neutral
  Version           : 1000.18362.329.0
> PackageFullName   : Microsoft.MicrosoftEdgeDevToolsClient_1000.18362.329.0_neutral_neutral_8wekyb3d8bbwe
> InstallLocation   : C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdgeDevToolsClient_8wekyb3d8bbwe
  IsFramework       : False
> PackageFamilyName : Microsoft.MicrosoftEdgeDevToolsClient_8wekyb3d8bbwe
  PublisherId       : 8wekyb3d8bbwe
  IsResourcePackage : False
  IsBundle          : False
  SignatureKind     : System
  Status            : Ok

> Name              : Microsoft.EdgeDevtoolsPlugin
  Publisher         : CN=Microsoft Windows, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
  Architecture      : Neutral
  ResourceId        : neutral
  Version           : 10.0.18362.329
> PackageFullName   : Microsoft.EdgeDevtoolsPlugin_10.0.18362.329_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
> InstallLocation   : C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.EdgeDevtoolsPlugin_cw5n1h2txyewy
  IsFramework       : False
> PackageFamilyName : Microsoft.EdgeDevtoolsPlugin_cw5n1h2txyewy
  PublisherId       : cw5n1h2txyewy
  IsResourcePackage : False
  IsBundle          : False
```

Comment: Compare `(Get-AppxPackage)[0].GetType()` and `(Get-AppxPackage)[0].ToString()` and you might see what happens when you look for a string on a specific object.

Or `Get-AppxPackage | foreach { $_.GetType().FullName }` and 
`Get-AppxPackage | foreach { $_.ToString() }` if you prefer.

The same phenomenon can be seen with files/dirs using Get-ChildItem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

As of PowerShell v7.3, to make [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) search non-string input by the same rich string representation you'd see in the console (terminal), you must pipe the input to `oss` first:

```bash
Get-AppxPackage | oss | Select-String -Pattern 'edge' -Context 3, 3
```

Note:

- This intermediate step should *not* be necessary, as discussed in [GitHub issue #10726](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10726).
- In fact it already isn't necessary when you're piping non-string input to an *external program* instead, say `findstr.exe`, because PowerShell then *implicitly* uses the rich string representation, because it has to send the input as (meaningful) *strings*.<sup>[1]</sup>
- As an aside: `Select-String` is convenient for searching through lines of text and - with `oss` - for searching the formatted string representations of objects, without having to know or care about their specific structure.

  - However, if you *do* know the structure, using OO techniques via different cmdlets, such as [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) and [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) is more robust. For instance, the following filters packages by their `.Name` property and then selects only the properties of interest:

    ```bash
    # Note: Get-AppXPackage *edge* would obviate the need for Where-Object
    Get-AppXPackage | 
      Where-Object Name -like *edge* |
      Select-Object Name, Version
    ```

---

##### Background information:

**`Select-String`, when given input *other* than strings, uses simple `.ToString()` stringification**<sup>[2]</sup> on each input object before looking for the given pattern.

In your case, the `[Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AppxPackage]` instances output by `Get-AppXPackage` stringify to the full package names (e.g., `Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_44.18362.387.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe`), which explains your output.

**In order to make `Select-String` search the *for-display* string representations of *objects*** - ***as they would print to the console* and as they would appear in a file saved to with `>` / `Out-File`** (`cat` is `Out-File`'s built-in alias on Windows) - you must, surprisingly, 
**use `Out-String -Stream`** as an intermediate pipeline segment; since PowerShell v5, if memory serves, you can use built-in **wrapper function [`oss`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Built-in_Functions#oss)** for brevity:

```bash
# oss is a built-in wrapper function for Out-String -Stream
Get-AppxPackage | oss | Select-String -Pattern 'edge' -Context 3, 3
```

[`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) uses PowerShell's [formatting system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml) to produce human-friendly *display* representations of the input objects, the same way that default console output, the `Format-*` cmdlets, and `>` / `Out-File` do.
`-Stream` causes the output lines to be sent through the pipeline *one by one*, so that `Select-String` can match individual lines.

---

Given that the solution is both non-obvious and cumbersome, **it would be nice if `Select-String` *directly* supported this behavior, ideally *by default***, but at least on an opt-in basis via a switch parameter - see [feature request #10726 on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10726) - up-vote the proposal there if you agree.

---

<sup>[1] As of v7.3, PowerShell only "speaks text" when communicating with external programs, so it has to create a string representation of non-string objects when passing data to them: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118502/45375). While it makes sense to *default* to the *for-display* string representation of such objects, note that this representation isn't meant for *programmatic processing*; for the latter, it's best to explicitly output a *structured text format*, such as JSON via `ConvertTo-Json`.</sup>

<sup>[2] More accurately, `.psobject.ToString()` is called, either as-is, or - if the object's `ToString` method supports an `IFormatProvider`-typed argument - as `.psobject.ToString([cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)` so as to obtain a *culture-invariant* representation - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375) for more information.</sup>