# Different behaviour and output when piping in CMD and PowerShell

Tags: powershell, encoding, cmd, pipe

I am trying to pipe the content of a file to a simple ASCII symmetrical encryption program i made. It's a simple program that reads input from STDIN and adds or subtracts a certain value (224) to each byte of the input.
For example: if the first byte is 4 and we want to encrypt, then it becomes 228. If it exceeds 255, the program just performs some modulo.

This is the output I get with cmd (test.txt contains "this is a test"):

```
    type .\test.txt | .\Crypt.exe --encrypt | .\Crypt.exe --decrypt
    this is a test
```

It also works the other way, thus it is a symmetrical encryption algorithm

```bsh
    type .\test.txt | .\Crypt.exe --decrypt | .\Crypt.exe --encrypt
    this is a test
```

But, the behaviour on PowerShell is different. When encrypting first, I get:

```bsh
    type .\test.txt | .\Crypt.exe --encrypt | .\Crypt.exe --decrypt
    this is a test_*
```

And that is what I get when decrypting first:

[image: Screen Shot]

Maybe is an encoding problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

- In ***Windows PowerShell*** and **[*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) *up to v7.3.x***, if you **need *raw byte handling*** and/or need to **prevent PowerShell from situationally adding a *trailing newline*** to your text data, **avoid the *PowerShell* pipeline altogether**, as shown below.
- **Workarounds are no longer necessary** in **v7.4+**: In v7.4, the previously *experimental* feature named [`PSNativeCommandPreserveBytePipe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/experimental-features#psnativecommandpreservebytepipe) became a *stable* feature:  `>` and `|` when applied to *external (native) programs* now act as *raw byte conduits*, i.e. they bypass the usual string-decoding and re-encoding cycle in favor of passing the raw data through.

  - However, **two limitations remain**:

    - Sending a *PowerShell string* through the pipeline to an *external program* still invariably causes a *newline* to be appended. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48372333/45375) for workarounds.
    - You cannot capture the raw bytes that form an external program's output *in memory* in PowerShell; see the bottom section for workarounds.

---

**For raw byte handling in *Windows PowerShell* and *PowerShell v7.3-*, shell out to `cmd` with `/c`** (on Windows; on Unix-like platforms / Unix-like Windows subsystems, use **`sh` or `bash` with `-c`**):

```bash
cmd /c 'type .\test.txt | .\Crypt.exe --encrypt | .\Crypt.exe --decrypt'
```

Use a similar technique to **save raw byte output in a *file*** - do *not* use *PowerShell*'s `>` operator:

```bash
cmd /c 'someexe > file.bin'
```

Note that **if you want to capture an external program's *text* output in a PowerShell variable or process it further in a PowerShell pipeline**, you need to make sure that `[Console]::OutputEncoding` matches your program's output character encoding (the active OEM code page, typically), which should be true by default in this case; see the next section for details.

**Generally, however, *byte* manipulation of *text* data is best avoided.**

---

There are ***two* separate problems**, only one of which has a simple solution:

---

**Problem 1**: There is indeed a character **encoding problem**, as you suspected:

**PowerShell invisibly** inserts itself as an intermediary in pipelines, even when sending data to and receiving data from *external programs*: It **converts data from and to .NET strings** (`System.String`), which are sequences of UTF-16 code units.

- As an aside: Even when using only PowerShell-native commands, this means that reading input from *files* and *saving them again* can result in a different character encoding, because the information about the original character encoding is not preserved once (string) data has been read into memory, and on saving it is the cmdlets' *default* character encoding that is used; while this default encoding is consistently BOM-less UTF-8 in *PowerShell (Core) 6+*, it varies by cmdlet in *Windows PowerShell* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/45375).

**In order to send to and receive data from *external programs* (such as `Crypt.exe` in  your case), you need to match *their* character encoding**; in your case, with a Windows console application that uses raw *byte* handling, the implied encoding is the system's active OEM code page.

- On ***sending* data**, PowerShell uses the encoding of the **`$OutputEncoding`** preference variable to *encode* (what is invariably treated as text) data, which defaults to ASCII(!) in Windows PowerShell, and (BOM-less) UTF-8 in PowerShell (Core).
- The ***receiving* end** is covered by default: PowerShell uses **`[Console]::OutputEncoding`** (which itself reflects the code page reported by `chcp`) for decoding data received, and on Windows this by default reflects the active OEM code page, both in Windows PowerShell and PowerShell [Core]<sup>[1]</sup>.

To fix your primary problem, you therefore need to **set `$OutputEncoding` to the active OEM code page**:

```bash
# Make sure that PowerShell uses the OEM code page when sending
# data to `.\Crypt.exe`
$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding
```

---

**Problem 2**: **PowerShell *invariably appends a trailing newline*** to data that doesn't already have one when piping data to external programs:

That is, `"foo" | .\Crypt.exe` doesn't send (the `$OutputEncoding`-encoded bytes representing) `"foo"` to `.\Crypt.exe`'s stdin, it sends `` "foo`r`n" `` on Windows; i.e., a (platform-appropriate) newline sequence (CRLF on Windows) is automatically and invariably appended (unless the string already happens to have a trailing newline).

This problematic behavior is discussed in [GitHub issue #5974](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5974) and also in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48372333/45375).

In your specific case, the implicitly appended `` "`r`n" `` is also subject to the byte-value-shifting, which means that the 1st `Crypt.exe` calls transforms it to `-*`, causing *another* `` "`r`n" `` to be appended when the data is sent to the 2nd `Crypt.exe` call.

The net result is an extra newline that is round-tripped (the intermediate `-*`), plus an *encrypted* newline that results in `φΩ`).

---

In short: If your input data had *no* trailing newline, you'll have to cut off the *last 4 characters* from the result (representing the round-tripped and the inadvertently encrypted newline sequences):

```bash
# Ensure that .\Crypt.exe output is correctly decoded.
$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding

# Invoke the command and capture its output in variable $result.
# Note the use of the `Get-Content` cmdlet; in PowerShell, `type`
# is simply a built-in *alias* for it.
$result = Get-Content .\test.txt | .\Crypt.exe --decrypt | .\Crypt.exe --encrypt

# Remove the last 4 chars. and print the result.
$result.Substring(0, $result.Length - 4)
```

Given that calling `cmd /c` as shown at the top of the answer works too, that hardly seems worth it.

---

#### How PowerShell handles pipeline data with external programs:

**Note**: The following ***mostly* applies to v7.4+ as well**, except where noted. *(PowerShell) v7.3-* is shorthand for both *older PowerShell (Core) versions (7.3.x and below)* and *Windows PowerShell*.

Unlike `cmd` (or POSIX-like shells such as `bash`):

- **PowerShell v7.3- doesn't support *raw byte data* in pipelines**.<sup>[2]</sup>
- **When talking to *external programs*, it only knows *text*** (whereas it passes .NET *objects* when talking to PowerShell's own commands, which is where much of its power comes from).

Specifically, this works as follows:

- When you **send data *to* an external program** via the pipeline (to its stdin stream):

  - In **v7.4+**, you now *can* now **send raw byte data** to an external program, *as a stream of `[byte]` instances or, preferably, for better performance, as a `[byte[]]` array*; one use case for this technique is to prevent PowerShell from appending a *trailing newline* to text, which invariably happens when a *string* is sent (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48372333/45375) for details and a 7.3- workaround); e.g.

    ```bash
    # Sends bytes with values 65 and 66 to findstr.exe, 
    # which interprets them as single-byte characters 'A' and 'B'
    # The unary form of "," in effect sends the byte array
    # *as a whole*, which improves performance.
    , [byte[]] (65, 66) | findstr . # -> 'AB'
    ```
  - **Otherwise - and *invariably* in v7.3- -** it is **converted to *text*** (strings) using the character encoding specified in the **`$OutputEncoding` preference variable**, which defaults to ASCII(!) in *Windows PowerShell*, and (BOM-less) UTF-8 in *PowerShell (Core)*.

    - **Caveat**: If you assign an encoding *with a BOM* to `$OutputEncoding`, PowerShell will *emit the BOM* as part of the *first* line of output sent to an external program; therefore, for instance, do not use `[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8` (which emits a BOM) in Windows PowerShell, and use `[System.Text.Utf8Encoding]::new()` (which doesn't) instead.
    - If the data is *not* captured or redirected by PowerShell, encoding problems may not always become apparent, namely if an external program is implemented in a way that uses the *Windows Unicode console API* to print to the display.
  - Something that isn't already text (a string) is stringified using PowerShell's default output formatting (the same format you see when you print to the console), with an **important caveat**:

    - **If the (last) input object already *is* a string that doesn't itself have a *trailing newline*, one is *invariably appended*** (and even an existing trailing newline is replaced with the platform-native one, if different).

      - This behavior can cause problems, as discussed in [GitHub issue #5974](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5974) and also in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48372333/45375).
- When you **capture / redirect data *from* an external program** (from its stdout stream), it is invariably **decoded as *lines of text*** (strings), based on the encoding specified in **`[Console]::OutputEncoding`**, which defaults to the active OEM code page on Windows (surprisingly, in *both* PowerShell editions, as of v7.0-preview6<sup>[1]</sup>).
- PowerShell-internally text is represented using the .NET [`System.String` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string), which is based on UTF-16 code units (often loosely, but incorrectly called "Unicode"<sup>[3]</sup>).

**In *Windows PowerShell* and PowerShell (Core) *up to v7.3.x only***, the above **also applies**:

- when **piping data *between* external programs**,
- when **data is *redirected to a file***; that is, irrespective of the source of the data and its original character encoding, PowerShell uses *its* default encoding(s) when sending data to files; in *Windows PowerShell*, `>` produces  UTF-16LE-encoded files (with BOM), whereas PowerShell (Core) sensibly defaults to BOM-less UTF-8 (consistently, across file-writing cmdlets).

In **v7.4+**, PowerShell **now streams *raw bytes* in the two scenarios above**, which not only improves performance noticeably, but prevents potential data corruption due to the previous as-text interpretation.

---

Note that **capturing raw byte data from external programs *in memory*** isn't directly possible: on assignment to a variable or on processing via a *PowerShell* command, the as-text interpretation still invariably applies; the simplest workaround is:

- **v7.4+**: Use `>` to redirect the external-program call to a file, and read that file with [`[System.IO.File::ReadAllBytes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes), for instance; as always when passing file-system paths to .NET methods, be sure to pass *full* paths, because .NET's working directory usually differs from PowerShell's.
- **v7.3-**: Call the external program *via the platform-native shell* and use *its* `>` operator to capture the raw byte output in a file (`cmd /c 'foo.exe ... > file` on Windows, `sh -c 'foo ... > file'` on Unix-like platforms), then read the file in PowerShell, as above.

---

<sup>[1] In PowerShell (Core), given that `$OutputEncoding` commendably already defaults to UTF-8, it would make sense to have `[Console]::OutputEncoding` be the same - i.e., for the active code page to be effectively `65001` on Windows, as suggested in [GitHub issue #7233](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7233).</sup>

<sup>[2] With input from a *file*, the closest you can get to raw byte handling is to read the file as a *.NET `System.Byte` array* with `Get-Content -AsByteStream` (PowerShell (Core)) / `Get-Content -Encoding Byte` (Windows PowerShell), but the only way you can further process such as an array is to pipe to a *PowerShell* command that is designed to handle a byte array, or by passing it to a .NET type's *method* that expects a byte array. If you tried to send such an array to an *external program* via the pipeline, *each byte would be sent as its decimal string representation on its own line*.</sup>

<sup>[3] *Unicode* is the name of the abstract *standard* describing a "global alphabet". In concrete use, it has various standard *encodings*, UTF-8 and UTF-16 being the most widely used.</sup>

Comment: Wow! So much for a stream being a byte stream. Great information. Many thanks.

Comment: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Use-RawPipeline is a good alternative until PowerShell adds a native way to handle this.